# Is there an interpreter for C?

Tags: c, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I was wondering if there is something like an interpreter for C.  That is, in a Linux terminal I can type in "python" and then code in that interpreter.  (I'm not sure interpreter the right word).  This is really helpful for testing different things out and I'm curious if something similar exists for C.  Though I doubt it.  The only thing I can think of that would do it would be the C shell...

Comment: The correct word for what you want is "shell" or "prompt" or "REPL" (Read-Eval-Print-Loop, in reference to the 4 Lisp commands that must be joined to make a Lisp interpreter in Lisp), but an interpreter would work.

Comment: As an aside, the term you are looking for is REPL (Read Evaluate Print Loop).

Comment: duplicate of [Is there a REPL for C programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10766900/309483)

Comment: The preferred word is actually "interactive" environment for C. An interactive environment opens up a shell or prompt specific to the language. REPL is also good.

Comment: A comprehensive list of interpreters and compilers for C/C++ can be found here: https://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml

Answer (score 71, accepted):

[There are many](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%20interpreter) - if you narrow down the scope of your question we might be able to suggest some specific to your needs.

A notable interpreter is "[Ch: A C/C++ Interpreter for Script Computing](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184402054)"  detailed in Dr. Dobbs:

> Ch is a complete C interpreter that
> supports all language features and
> standard libraries of the ISO C90
> Standard, but extends C with many
> high-level features such as string
> type and computational arrays as
> first-class objects.

[Ch standard is freeware](http://www.softintegration.com/products/chstandard/) but not open source.  Only Ch professional has the plotting capabilities and other features one might want.

I've never looked at this before, but having a c interpreter on hand sounds very useful, and something I will likely add to my toolset.  Thanks for the question!

---

Edit:

Just found out that one of my favorite compilers, [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/), will execute C scripts:

> It also handles C script files (just
> add the shebang line
> "#!/usr/local/bin/tcc -run" to the
> first line of your C source code file
> on Linux to have it executed directly.
>
> TCC can read C source code from
> standard input when '-' is used in
> place of 'infile'. Example:
>
> ```
> echo 'main(){puts("hello");}' | tcc -run -
> ```

Comment: I wish a version of CH was available under an OSI approved license, so it could be distributed. You can design really nice utilities using their interpreter, unfortunately they're just too problematic to bundle.

Comment: That would be nice.  Freeware is better than nothing, but until someone does it...

Comment: Weirdly, `tcc` exits with status `10` by default. It looks like you have to explicitly add a `return 0` giving `echo 'main(){puts("hello"); return 0;}' | tcc -run -`

Answer (score 18):

[picoc](http://code.google.com/p/picoc/) - A very small C interpreter

> PicoC is a very small C interpreter for scripting. It was originally
>   written as the script language for a UAV's on-board flight system.
>   It's also very suitable for other robotic, embedded and non-embedded
>   applications.

Answer (score 9):

the ROOT project provides a very functional C and C++ interpreter called [Cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint).  I'm quite fond of it.  It takes a little getting used to interpretively, though.

TCC is a very good choice as well, but i'm not able to vouch for its REPL

Comment: Isn't the ROOT team phasing out Cint?

Comment: @Zboson "CERN has switch to a new interpreter, cling.

 

CINT is not supported by CERN anymore"

Comment: ROOT replaced cint by cling. So cling can be taken as updated recommendation. (though - see other answers - cling is C++, not C, if that's relevant, though iirc cint also did some C++)

Answer (score 8):

Probably. There are several for c++. See [Have you used any of the C++ interpreters (not compilers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers/72792#72792) for examples. Certainly [cint](http://root.cern.ch/root/CintInterpreter.html) will eat nearly any c code with good results, and [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) is so fast that you can use it like a interpreter.

Answer (score 7):

Give a look to the [Ch Interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter).

> Ch is an embeddable C/C++ interpreter
>   for cross-platform scripting, shell
>   programming, 2D/3D plotting, numerical
>   computing, and embedded scripting.

Answer (score 6):

I know we use CINT in class. It seemed pretty good you might want to give it a try!

Answer (score 5):

Check Out [iGCC](http://www.artificialworlds.net/wiki/IGCC/IGCC)

Answer (score 4):

`cinterp` is one for a start.

Comment: Are you referring to https://github.com/danielkeller/cinterp or to http://free-compilers.sharnoff.org/TOOL/C-12.html ? A link would improve this answer ...

Answer (score 2):

**[ccons](https://github.com/asvitkine/ccons)** appears to satisfy your constraints:

> The goal of the ccons project is to create an interactive console for the C programming language, similar to "python" and "irb" for Python and Ruby respectively. The project builds on top of clang and llvm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CompCert. Here are some examples: http://compcert.inria.fr/man/manual004.html

Answer (score 2):

More recently there is Cling (based on LLVM/Clang)

http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling

Comment: It is for C++, not C.

Answer (score 1):

It has been done, even though the vast majority of C work is compiled.  One example is [CH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

CERN has a toolkit called ROOT, which is meant mainly for scientific or data analysis etc.. purposes but it has a Clang - based C/C++ Interpreter called `Cling`.

They were using a C interpreter called **CINT** before they adapted `Cling`. CINT is lightweight & still seems to be available for download.

I think you may get some other by carefully searching through Wikipedia list articles.