# pyYAML - Error - Attribute Error: no attribute "load"

Tags: python, pyyaml

Well, I'm playing with pyYAML. I installed the version for Python 2.7 with the Windows installer.

It imports just fine:

```
import yaml
```

and it throws no errors.

But, if I do this:

```
import yaml

f = open("sets.yml")
dataMap = yaml.load(f)
f.close()

print dataMap
```

It throws an attribute error and says 'module' object has no attribute 'load'.

I tried dump, and got the same thing. Also same thing for importing like this:

```
from yaml import load
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Oh, and also, I thought it was weird -- whenever I run the script, it created a .pyc of it. Why is that?

Comment: For `.pyc`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files

Comment: For YAML, what library are you using? Is there a `yaml.py`file in your folder?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If another file named yaml.py is on your sys.path BEFORE the actual PyYaml library, you'll pick up and import that yaml.py file.  This includes if you've named your own file yaml.py.

The fact that you're getting yaml.pyc in your directory indicates that this is exactly what you're doing.  Your import yaml statement is loading in your own yaml.py file, which causes the interpreter to compile it to yaml.pyc for more efficient running.

Rename the yaml.py file in your directory.  Do not name any python file you're working on with the same name as any existing python module you're using, as a general rule.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've done this before. I think it happens because I don't want to name it "test.py", because my desktop gets cluttered with things along those lines when testing out a new module.

Hopefully I'll remember this.

Answer (score 1):

PyYAML-3.10 has load():

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/clusterFix$ easy_install pyyaml
Searching for pyyaml
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyyaml/
Reading http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML
Best match: PyYAML 3.10
Downloading http://pyyaml.org/download/pyyaml/PyYAML-3.10.zip
Processing PyYAML-3.10.zip
Running PyYAML-3.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-2PnFkZ/PyYAML-3.10/egg-dist-tmp-kCMq7S
build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/check_libyaml.c:2:18: fatal error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
(if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
 specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
 modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding PyYAML 3.10 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PyYAML-3.10-py2.6-linux-i686.egg
Processing dependencies for pyyaml
Finished processing dependencies for pyyaml
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/clusterFix$ python
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jun 13 2011, 22:03:32) 
[GCC 4.6.1 20110608 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yaml
>>> dir(yaml)
['AliasEvent', 'AliasToken', 'AnchorToken', 'BaseDumper', 'BaseLoader', 'BlockEndToken', 'BlockEntryToken', 'BlockMappingStartToken', 'BlockSequenceStartToken', 'CollectionEndEvent', 'CollectionNode', 'CollectionStartEvent', 'DirectiveToken', 'DocumentEndEvent', 'DocumentEndToken', 'DocumentStartEvent', 'DocumentStartToken', 'Dumper', 'Event', 'FlowEntryToken', 'FlowMappingEndToken', 'FlowMappingStartToken', 'FlowSequenceEndToken', 'FlowSequenceStartToken', 'KeyToken', 'Loader', 'MappingEndEvent', 'MappingNode', 'MappingStartEvent', 'Mark', 'MarkedYAMLError', 'Node', 'NodeEvent', 'SafeDumper', 'SafeLoader', 'ScalarEvent', 'ScalarNode', 'ScalarToken', 'SequenceEndEvent', 'SequenceNode', 'SequenceStartEvent', 'StreamEndEvent', 'StreamEndToken', 'StreamStartEvent', 'StreamStartToken', 'TagToken', 'Token', 'ValueToken', 'YAMLError', 'YAMLObject', 'YAMLObjectMetaclass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '__with_libyaml__', 'add_constructor', 'add_implicit_resolver', 'add_multi_constructor', 'add_multi_representer', 'add_path_resolver', 'add_representer', 'compose', 'compose_all', 'composer', 'constructor', 'dump', 'dump_all', 'dumper', 'emit', 'emitter', 'error', 'events', 'load', 'load_all', 'loader', 'nodes', 'parse', 'parser', 'reader', 'representer', 'resolver', 'safe_dump', 'safe_dump_all', 'safe_load', 'safe_load_all', 'scan', 'scanner', 'serialize', 'serialize_all', 'serializer', 'tokens']
```

Answer (score 1):

@michaelfilms answer helped me.

I named my testfile `yaml.py` and imported PyYAML via `import yaml` so it **considered itself at source**. I **renamed** my file to `test_yaml.py`.

I had to update the import to `import yaml` instead of aut-updated `import test_yaml` and everything works fine now.