# python syntax mess: name is not defined

Tags: python, syntax

I've been learning from 'Learn Python the Hard Way' and this particular piece of code gives me a lot of headache:

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sort the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = brea_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Once the module is imported I get errors:

```
>>> import ex25
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
>>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ex25.py", line 4, in break_words
    return words
NameError: global name 'words' is not defined
```

Where did I go wrong? I checked the code millions of times...

Comment: I cannot reproduce this... I don't get that error.

Comment: Why not have break_words just return stuff.split(' ')?  Doesn't explain the error, but gets you closer to working code...

Comment: Note in `sort_sentence()` you have a typo `brea_words()` instead of `break_words()`.

Comment: Think @JakobBowyer might be right - this should work (despite the error in `sort_sentence`) - so you probably have an old `.pyc` that isn't being removed for some reason, so the correct code is not being called.

Comment: Thanks for trying, Felix! It's a mystery.

Comment: deleted the pyc file already. What's that by the way?

Comment: Its compiled python code. Its kinda a cheat copy of your python code that executes and imports slightly faster

Comment: @alkopop79 What are pyc files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files

Comment: You don't need to delete the `.pyc` file.  Just save your `.py` file again and Python will recompile.  Your code looks fine and there should not be an error in `break_words`.  Make sure to restart the Python interpreter (or use `reload()`) after you change the source file.

Comment: Just had to move it to a different folder. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Different *folder*?  Do you believe in magic?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried running

```
reload(ex25)
```

?  If you import a file, then change that file, the python process doesn't know that you changed it.  You have to either restart, or tell it to look at the module again.

Answer (score 1):

As I say in my comment I think your pyc file is being imported rather than your py code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose above answer is enough - you need to reload module. On the NFS filesystem I saw troubles with not recompiled python code after it was changed (and old pyc file was used). If 'reload' does not work you can try remove pyc file and restart python.

```
  ddzialak@pld ~$ python
  Python 2.7.2 (default, Aug 16 2011, 10:09:58)
  [GCC 4.6.1 20110714 (release)] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import ex25
  >>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
  >>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
  >>> print words
  ['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
```