# can std::regex be more faster?

Tags: c++, regex

These days I read some [paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433579/what-are-motivations-behind-compiling-to-byte-code), they say AST is much slower than bytecode. So can we use such fact to speed up `std::regex`.
For example, suppose I have a `regex_exprission` ".*\.txt" and want to use `std::regex_match` later. What if I write a parse function, to convert the `regex_exprission` to

```cpp
bool judge(const std::string& str) {
    return
        str[str.size() - 4] == '.' &&
        str[str.size() - 3] == 't' &&
        str[str.size() - 2] == 'x' &&
        str[str.size() - 1] == 't';
}
```

then use gcc/msvc to compile it and load dynamic library to get the compiled function judge, use judge to replace `std::regex_match(_, regex_exprission)`. Would it be much faster?

Comment: All I see here is an unsafe, inefficient function. I have full confidence that `std::regex` would build a more efficient state machine for such a trivial expression. Of course, if you want to check this for yourself, write a program to test it.

Comment: Side-note: see [std::string::ends_with](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/ends_with)

Comment: It's also wrong. The regex matches "123.txtfile" but your version doesn't. And your version exhibits undefined behavior when given the string "4”.

Comment: @paddy Better still: pass the argument as a `std::filesystem::path` and call `.extension`

Comment: To be fair to the OP, they are talking about automatically converting regexes into code. The example given may be bugged but the question is about the principle. The bit I don't follow is the assumption that `std::regex` must use an AST and not byte code. Is that true in principle or in practice?

Comment: @RaymondChen, do you use std::regex_match?

Comment: @john I'm not the expert of such situation, but I think the answer is true. It's not very precise to call it AST, but they are the same thing. In fact, if we do std::regex in original way, there will be many code to handle the regex, and when we run std::regex_match or std::regex_search, it have to jump for code to code, which will cost time. But if we compile it to bytecode, we don't have to jump, all code will be organized together, just run one by one, so it will be fast.

Comment: @macomphy But I don't see what prevents a `std::regex` implementation from doing a compilation to byte code as well. The first time you use a particular regex it could compile it to byte code, and then reuse that byte code on each subsequent use. I don't know if any particular implementation actually does that, but I don't see why it's not possible.

Comment: @john sorry, it's possible in principle. I just think it's too complex to complete it.

Comment: IIRC, `std::regex` is going to be [deprecated](https://github.com/sg16-unicode/sg16/issues/57) in some future C++ standard.

Comment: Note also that your linked "paper" is just a StackOverflow question. If that counts as a paper, then congratulations, you just published a paper. (There is an `optimize` flag which implementations can use to decide whether to compile to bytecode. I don't know if anyone actually uses it.)

Comment: std::regex is horrible due to the standard constraints. It manages to be much slower than boost::regex, in which it was based. Even Python and Perl come ahead. `hscan` comes on top. There is this regex shootout fyi https://github.com/HFTrader/regex-performance

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Different regex engine has different syntax and ability, are they regex engine the same?

Comment: @macomphy yes they are fungible as you can see in the tests