# Does Ruby have an equivalent to the __pycache__ folder in Python?

Tags: ruby, python-3.x

In Python, after you run a program, there are caches saved in the folders named `__pycache__`. For futher explanation of the functionality of these folders, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/what-is-pycache). Does Ruby have an equivalent of this? If not, why?

Comment: I think the simple answer is "It depends on the implementation of Ruby."  You will find similar files that are bytecode for Rubinius for example.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look into that. I was aware that JRuby would compile into bytecode, but hadn't looked at Rubinius that closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't haven an equivalent. It just wouldn't make sense: Ruby is a programming language. A programming language is an abstract mathematical concept, a specification. Putting such detailed things as the name of the directory of the byte code cache in a language would be way too restrictive: what if somebody wants to implement Ruby on a platform which doesn't have files? What if someone wants to implement Ruby on a platform where underscores are illegal in directory names? What if someone wants to implement Ruby with an interpreter instead of a compiler?

There *are*, however, some Ruby *implementations* which *do* compile to byte code. YARV and Rubinius are two examples of those. YARV only compiles in memory, whereas Rubinius caches the compiled byte code on disk. In fact, it *must* have the ability to save and read the compiled byte code because the compiler *itself* is written in Ruby, and otherwise it would have to compile itself in order to be able to compile any code, but in order to compile itself it would first have to compile itself and in order to that it would first have to …

But that is a private internal implementation detail of Rubinius. It is *not* part of Ruby nor *should* it be.