# Python EOFerror when importing a module after unplugging Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a python3.2 script running from rc.local at startup on a raspberry pi - Raspbian OS, it imports a file called `inouts.py` module that i made and lives in the same directory, ive updated the `sys.path.append(...)`

The script worked fine for weeks.  Today I had to unplug the rpi without shutting down.

After rebooting the script fails to open and gives the error:
`EOFError: EOF read where not expected`

The `inouts.py` is definitely the module causing the error as I have it on its own line.

If I change the name from `inouts.py` to `inouts2.py` the script works.
If I run it as python2 it also works.

Can anybody point me in the right direction on what might be causing this filename to cause this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "rf2.py", line 3, in <module>
import inouts
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

Comment: care to share something to help with? code snippet? stack trace?

Comment: added the error message, will get more information soon.

Comment: Is there an `inouts.pyc` file?  If so, try deleting that.

Comment: Yes I deleted that too, still no change

Comment: I found a file in the __pycache__ folder called inouts.cpython-32.pyc i renamed it and it works...can anyone tell me what thats about?

Comment: You can read more about the `__pycache__` folder [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/).

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I have resolved the issue by adding -B to the command that runs the python script which stops the creation of the __pycache__ folder.  I have some understanding of the problem but not enough to give a comprehensive answer and I would still like to know how to keep __pycache__ without it causing the error.

Comment: I think this might be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1058884 .

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem myself today by deleting all of the `*.pyc` files in the `__pycache__` subdirectory.

Comment: There are two _ blanks before and two after pycache -- which don't show here.