# AttributeError when importing modules in Python 3

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, attributeerror

I am trying to write a script that makes use of the json and requests modules. Before I wrote the script, I was playing around with commands on the interactive shell, and since creating an actual file for my code, everything has somehow broken. The first time I ran the code, a **pycache** folder appeared in the folder and I think that is somehow breaking everthing. The code, when run line by line in the shell, no longer works either with the presence of this **pycache** folder. My code is as follows:

```
import json
import requests
r = requests.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/78c2f37e6d924b1b/hourly/q/CA/Berkeley.json')
data = json.loads(r.text)
for x in range(0, 35):
    print(data['hourly_forecast'][x]['FCTTIME']['hour'])
```

This should print out all the hours in the weather forecast, but I get an "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'. In this folder, I also previously had another program that used external modules that also no long works with the presence of the **pycache** folder, so I am almost certain that it is causing the problems. However, deleting it doesn't fix anything as the code still doesn't work, and it just gets recreated.

EDIT: The problem was solved by deleting the entire buggy directory and rewriting everything.

Comment: Are you running some kind of test before? Try running with `python -B` and see if this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

The most common reason for `'module' object has no attribute 'xxx'`, where 'xxx' is an attribute that you 'know'  'module' does have, is this: your program is in a directory that has a 'module.py' that you have forgotten about for the modment.  So `import module` imports your module instead of the intended module in the stdlib (or elsewhere).  There have been multiple examples of this problem posted on python-list.  At least two were due to a forgotten-about random.py in the same directory.

The situation would have been clearer if you had posted the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this SO question [What is **pycache**?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/what-is-pycache), see answer from @scott_fakename:

> When you run a program in python, the interpreter compiles it to
>   bytecode first (this is an oversimplification) and stores it in the
>   **pycache** folder. If you look in there you will find a bunch of files sharing the names of the .py files in your project's folder,
>   only their extentions will be either .pyc or .pyo. These are
>   bytecode-compiled and optimized bytecode-compiled versions of your
>   program's files, respectively.
>
> As a programmer, you can largely just ignore it... All it does is make
>   your program start a little faster. When your scripts change, they
>   will be recompiled, and if you delete the files or the whole and run
>   your program again, they will reappear (unless you specifically
>   suppress that behavior)
>
> If you are using cpython (which is the most common, as it's the
>   reference implementation) and you don't want that folder, then you can
>   suppress it by starting the interpreter with the -B flag, for example
>
> python -B foo.py
>
> Another option, as noted by tcaswell, is to set the
>   environment variable PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE to any value (according
>   to python's man page, any "non empty string").

So, you can either run:

```
python -B xxx.py
```

Or, set environment variable:

```
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE = 1
```

Comment: I saw that answer, and running python with the -B flag, and though it prevents the __pycache__ folder from creating, the AttributeError still shows. Setting environment variable doesn't help either.

Comment: are you within virtualenv? perhaps a reinstallation is required in your case

Comment: what is virtualenv? Also python itself is not the issue, if I change to another directory everything is fine. Should I just delete the folder and retry everything?

Comment: @thenorm, yea if change a directory will resolve this. I meant reinstall `json` modules if you are under virtualenv. virtualenv is a wrapper to separate your `pip` modules installtion from system wide installation

Comment: I don't think I need to reinstall json modules. Anyway, I deleted the entire directory and rewrote everything, this seems to work. Any idea why this was happening?

Comment: @thenorm, I am not entirely sure, but seems it has something to do with the `.pyc`.

Comment: This is really strange, because deleting the .pyc didn't help either. Anyway, thanks for the help!