# AttributeError when loading pptx module in Python

Tags: python, python-pptx

I get the reoccuring `AttributeError` when trying to import the python-pptx module:

```
import pptx

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
...
----> 8 import pptx.exc as exceptions
...
AttributeError: module 'pptx' has no attribute 'exc'
```

I am using the JupyterNotebook and have already reinstalled python-pptx using `pip uninstall python-pptx` `pip install python-pptx`. On stackoverflow, I found a related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787309/attributeerror-when-importing-modules-in-python-3).

Even as I understand that it might not be loading the right module, I do not know how to proceed further in order to resolve the issue. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you name your program `pptx.py` by any chance? Python would preferentially load that module instead of the library version.

You can find out what module was loaded with this at the Python prompt:

```
>>> import pptx
>>> pptx.__file__
'/somedir/.../python-pptx/pptx/__init__.pyc'
```

That may help narrow things down.

Comment: I have tried it and the module is loading correctly.