# Python3 project remove __pycache__ folders and .pyc files

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, delete-file

What is the BEST way to clear out all the `__pycache__`  folders and `.pyc/.pyo` files from a python3 project. I have seen multiple users suggest the `pyclean` script bundled with Debian, but this does not remove the folders. I want a simple way to clean up the project before pushing the files to my DVS.

Comment: It may also be worth considering changing the cache directory to avoid this issue alltogether. For example, `export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=/tmp/pycache`.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I found the answer myself when I mistyped `pyclean` as pycclean:

```py
No command 'pycclean' found, did you mean:
  Command 'py3clean' from package 'python3-minimal' (main)
  Command 'pyclean' from package 'python-minimal' (main)
  pycclean: command not found
```

Running `py3clean .` cleaned it up very nicely.

Comment: py3clean is more conservative than @V.Gamula's command: it does not delete .pyc files generated from source files that have been deleted since.

Comment: As of may/2017, in macos/homebrew, I had to use the package pycleaner from pip, and the command to execute it is pycleaner. Python 2 only.

Comment: python3-minimal seems to be available on Debian only (not finding it on RHEL, CentOS, brew, MacOS)

Comment: oddly enough, my installed py3clean (3.5.1-3) does nothing actually, clears none of those files and simply silently returns (python 3.6.5).

Comment: This only seems to work if the executable is available under the specific name. This is not a general solution but more like Debian/Ubuntu only.

Comment: It does not delete `__pycache__` folders, nor `.pyc` files (tested on debian)

Answer (score 440):

You can do it manually with the next command:

```
find . | grep -E "(/__pycache__$|\.pyc$|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```

This will remove all `.pyc` and `.pyo` files as well as `__pycache__` directories recursively starting from the current directory.

Comment: The command is dirty. It will also delete `*__pycache__`, `*.pyc*` and it doesn't distinguish between files and directories. Most of the generated `rm` commands will also be superfluous.

Comment: This is just wrong. That's not how you use `find` nor `grep` nor `rm` and it could be dangerous for any current working directory that might contain `useful.pycle.json` or `important_deployment_setting_about__pycache__.txt` etc. Which I wouldn't rule out on the entire user base of SO. Not to mention how (dangerously `rm -rf`) broken `xargs` would be by a file with whitespace in the name. So I edited it…

Comment: @dwanderson I think you're talking about a different answer; or does SO edit history no longer show the complete history EG there was a version in 2017 that isn't shown there?

Comment: Doesn't work on OSX `grep: parentheses not balanced`

Comment: is it safe to delete these files ?

Comment: this command is not safe. make sure about what you are going to do here, if you are inside the python virtual environment and if you executes this command it will remove the entire .pyc in the virtual environment as well.

Comment: @dlamblin So is it correct now? If so, please delete the comment, it kind of makes me afraid to use it as is.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Is it still true after the edits?

Comment: @Gulzar it still doesn't distinguish between files and directories.

Comment: @Gulzar also note other comments

Answer (score 183):

### macOS & Linux

BSD's `find` implementation on macOS is different from GNU find - this is compatible with both BSD and GNU find. Start with a globbing implementation, using `-name` and the `-o` for *or* - Put this function in your `.bashrc` file:

```
pyclean () {
    find . -type f -name '*.py[co]' -delete -o -type d -name __pycache__ -delete
}
```

Then `cd` to the directory you want to recursively clean, and type `pyclean`.

#### GNU find-only

This is a GNU find, only (i.e. Linux) solution, but I feel it's a little nicer with the regex:

```
pyclean () {
    find . -regex '^.*\(__pycache__\|\.py[co]\)$' -delete
}
```

### Any platform, using Python 3

On Windows, you probably don't even have `find`. You do, however, probably have Python 3, which starting in 3.4 has the convenient `pathlib` module:

```
python3 -Bc "import pathlib; [p.unlink() for p in pathlib.Path('.').rglob('*.py[co]')]"
python3 -Bc "import pathlib; [p.rmdir() for p in pathlib.Path('.').rglob('__pycache__')]"
```

The [`-B`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#id1) flag tells Python not to write `.pyc` files. (See also the [`PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE) environment variable.)

The above abuses list comprehensions for looping, but when using `python -c`, style is rather a secondary concern. Alternatively we could abuse (for example) `__import__`:

```
python3 -Bc "for p in __import__('pathlib').Path('.').rglob('*.py[co]'): p.unlink()"
python3 -Bc "for p in __import__('pathlib').Path('.').rglob('__pycache__'): p.rmdir()"
```

#### Critique of an answer

The top answer used to say:

> ```
> find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
> ```

This would seem to be less efficient because it uses three processes. `find` takes a regular expression, so we don't need a separate invocation of `grep`. Similarly, it has `-delete`, so we don't need a separate invocation of `rm` —and contrary to a comment here, it *will* delete non-empty directories so long as they get emptied by virtue of the regular expression match.

From the `xargs` man page:

> ```
> find /tmp -depth -name core -type f -delete
> ```
>
> Find files named core in or below the directory /tmp and delete them,
>   but more efficiently than in the previous example (because we avoid
>   the need to use fork(2) and exec(2) to launch rm and we don't need
>   the extra xargs process).

Comment: You could probably get the python version to one line by using `shutil.rmtee` on the `__pycache__` directories instead of emptying them first; a one-liner might be nice for an easy alias. I'm a big fan of `Path` right now, though, so I think I'll use that version in my script.

Comment: ```python -Bc "import pathlib; import shutil; [shutil.rmtree(p) for p in pathlib.Path('.').rglob('__pycache__')]"
```

Comment: For some reason the `-delete` flags on `find` don't seem to be working for me on macOS inside of a Makefile, even when explicitly setting `SHELL` to bash.  But piping to xargs to delete worked fine.  Not really sure what that's about.

Comment: For powershell user `Get-ChildItem -Recurse | where {$_.name -Match '__pycache__'} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse`

Answer (score 56):

Since this is a Python 3 project, you only need to delete `__pycache__` directories -- all `.pyc`/`.pyo` files are inside them.

```
find . -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -r {} \+
```

<sub>(Note: using `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -r {} \+` won't work because it [can't delete non-empty directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164873/find-delete-does-not-delete-non-empty-directories))</sub>

---

Alternatively, if you're doing this in a directory that's under revision control, you can tell the RCS to ignore `__pycache__` directories recursively. Then, at the required moment, just clean up all the ignored files. This will likely be more convenient because there'll probably be more to clean up than just `__pycache__`.

Comment: No, not all `.pyc` files are inside it.

Comment: @V.Gamula This is a considerably more safe command than the one ~114 people were lucky enough did not bite them with permanent deletion of a mistaken match.

Comment: @MartinThoma in a python3 only project?

Comment: Am I the only one getting `Directory not empty` with the second variant here?

Comment: find ./ -type f -name '*.pyc' -delete -print && find ./ -type d -name "__pycache__" -delete -print

Answer (score 50):

If you need a **permanent solution** for keeping Python cache files out of your project directories:

Starting with **Python 3.8**, you can use the environment variable `PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX` to define a cache directory for Python.

From the Python docs:

> If this is set, Python will write `.pyc` files in a mirror directory tree at this path, instead of in `__pycache__` directories within the source tree. This is equivalent to specifying the `-X pycache_prefix=PATH` option.

**Example**

If you add the following line to your `~/.profile` shell configuration file on Linux:

```bash
export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX="${HOME}/.cache/Python"
```

Python won't create the annoying `__pycache__` directories in your project directory; instead, it will put all of them under `~/.cache/Python`

If you work Linux and macOS, you could add these lines to `~/.bash_profile` / `~/.profile` for a cross-platform shell configuration (which also creates the folder as required):

```bash
# set python cache folder for .pyc files:
#   https://stackoverflow.com/a/57415054
case "${OSTYPE}" in
    darwin*)
        folder="${HOME}/Library/Caches/Python"
        if [[ ! -d "${folder}" ]]; then mkdir -p "${folder}"; fi
        export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX="${folder}"
        ;;
    linux-*)
        folder="${HOME}/.cache/Python"
        if [[ ! -d "${folder}" ]]; then mkdir -p "${folder}"; fi
        export PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX="${folder}"
        ;;
    *)
        printf "WARNING: unsupported operating system '%s'; "`
              `'not setting PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX' "${OSTYPE}" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Yes. It's a great feature! All OS distros should enable it by default. Such as adding `PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=/var/cache/python` into /etc/environment

Comment: @Keelung: I am not sure if it is advisable to use a system-wide folder such as `/var/cache`: This might clash with the cache of other users on the system - especially when configuring this on a "distribution level" (i.e. making that setting the default for all users).

Answer (score 28):

The command I've used:

`find . -type d -name  "__pycache__" -exec rm -r {} +`

Explains:

1. First finds all `__pycache__` folders in current directory.
2. Execute `rm -r {} +` to delete each folder at step above (`{}`  signify for placeholder and `+` to end the command)

**Edited 1:**

I'm using Linux, to reuse the command I've added the line below to the `~/.bashrc` file

```
alias rm-pycache='find . -type d -name  "__pycache__" -exec rm -r {} +'
```

**Edited 2:**
If you're using **VS Code**, you don't need to remove `__pycache__` manually.
You can add the snippet below to `settings.json` file. After that, **VS Code** will hide all `__pycache__` folders for you

```
"files.exclude": {
     "**/__pycache__": true
}
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thanks this "ind . -type d -name  "__pycache__" -exec rm -r {} +" worked for me, was trying to find an easy way to delete all the pycache folder in my django project

Answer (score 26):

I'm running Python3 and pip3 on a Mac. For me, the solution was as follows
(In the root directory of my project):

```
pip3 install pyclean
pyclean .
```

I'd like to emphasize, since I see *many* answers which involve bash scripting, it is best practice in software to favour tested solutions to problems (which is exactly what an established python package represents) over a hand-rolled approach.

Comment: Assuming the established python package has tested all possible scenarios...

Comment: That seems an impossibility. It is also established practice to be selective about the problems we solve. If your use-case is genuinely unsupported by the common solutions, of course it makes sense to solve your unique use case. In such a case,  It may be that others share the same problem and your solution should be published.

Answer (score 13):

This is my alias that works both with Python 2 and Python 3 removing all `.pyc .pyo` files as well `__pycache__` directories recursively.

```
alias pyclean='find . -name "*.py[co]" -o -name __pycache__ -exec rm -rf {} +'
```

Answer (score 13):

There is a nice pip package.

```
pip install pyclean
pyclean --verbose .
```

done

Answer (score 9):

## Using PyCharm

### To remove Python compiled files

1. In the `Project Tool Window`, right-click a project or directory, where Python compiled files should be deleted from.
2. On the context menu, choose `Clean Python compiled files`.

The `.pyc` files residing in the selected directory are silently deleted.

Answer (score 8):

From the project directory type the following:

Deleting all **.pyc** files

`find . -path "*/*.pyc"  -delete`

Deleting all **.pyo** files:

`find . -path "*/*.pyo"  -delete`

Finally, to delete all **'__pycache__'**, type:

`find . -path "*/__pycache__" -type d -exec rm -r {} ';'`

If you encounter **permission denied** error, add **sudo** at the begining of all the above command.

Comment: Better add "-print" after "-delete".

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for the other answers, based on them this is what I used for my Debian package's `prerm` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

deb_package='package-name'
python_package='package_name'

if which pyclean >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    py3clean -p $deb_package
else
    dpkg -L $deb_package | grep ${python_package}$ | while read file
    do
        find ${file} -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -r {} \+
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time your project is under source control; in case if `git` is used, one can just run `git clean -d -f .` to clean up non-version controlled files; in case if Python cache files/directories are in `.gitignore`, you'll also need `-x` (also remove ignored files) or `-X` (remove only ignored files) command line switches.

Please note that if you have any temporary files that have to be saved, move them outside local repository or add to index tree before running `git clean` without `-X`.

Answer (score 1):

Empty the directories first and then remove them:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.pyc' -delete -print && find ./ -type d -name '__pycache__' -delete -print
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `rm -rf __pycache__`? Run `git add -A` afterwards to remove them from your repository and add `__pycache__/` to your .gitignore file.

Comment: He's not doing this manually. He's trying to add it to a script used in a Debian package. A debian package is not used with git but with the debian package manager or the apt installer.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it can be

```sh
#!/bin/bash

project_root_dir=$(pwd)

# 
# function _dcache deletes __pycache__ folders floating around python modules
# 
function _dcache() {
  find "$project_root_dir/inb" -name "__pycache__" > pycache

  while IFS= read -r cache_file; do
    rm -r $cache_file
  done < pycache

  rm pycache
}
```

This is what I use for my projects. You can give it a try.

Comment: have you considered the "pyclean" pip package? It does the job and likely covers edge cases that this script would not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a nested directory with multiple junk files, you can give the root directory to the following function and it will clear all subfolders from the junkies:

```
import os, shutil
def clean_all_from_junk(directory):
    def delete_junk(f):
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(f)
        except:
            os.unlink(f)
    msk_dirs = os.listdir(directory)  
    for f in msk_dirs:
        if f.startswith('.') or f=='__pycache__' or f.endswith('txt'):
            junk_p = os.path.join(directory, f)
            print('deleted-->', junk_p)
            delete_junk(junk_p)
        else:
            if os.path.isdir(f):
                subfolder_p = os.path.join(directory, f)
                clean_all_from_junk(subfolder_p)
    return 'All cleaned!'

 
clean_all_from_junk('path/to/root/directory')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted all the `__pycache__/` stuff and you still get `HINT: remove __pycache__/.pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules`, it may be caused by the second part of the error message - just **check that you don't have the two files with the exact names**.

Answer (score -16):

Please just go to your terminal then type:

```
$rm __pycache__
```

and it will be removed.

Comment: What you mean is if somebody has thousands of __pycache__ folders floating around a python project then (s)he can go with your approach and it will be fine? The questioner wants to automate this task so it will be helpful if you can provide a script that will perform the cleanup automatically. Thanks!

Comment: The bare minimum would be a `rm -r __pycache__`