# How to clear cache (or force recompilation) in numba

Tags: anaconda, numba

I have a fairly large codebase written in numba, and I have noticed that when the cache is enabled for a function calling another numba compiled function in another file, changes in the called function are not picked up when the called function is changed. The situation occurs when I have two files:

testfile2:

```
import numba

@numba.njit(cache=True)
def function1(x):
    return x * 10
```

testfile:

```
import numba
from tests import file1

@numba.njit(cache=True)
def function2(x, y):
    return y + file1.function1(x)
```

If in a jupyter notebook, I run the following:

```
# INSIDE JUPYTER NOTEBOOK
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "path/to/files/")
from tests import testfile

testfile.function2(3, 4)
>>> 34   # good value
```

However, if I change then change testfile2 to the following:

```
import numba

@numba.njit(cache=True)
def function1(x):
    return x * 1
```

Then I restart the jupyter notebook kernel and rerun the notebook, I get the following

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, "path/to/files/")
from tests import testfile

testfile.function2(3, 4)
>>> 34   # bad value, should be 7
```

Importing both files into the notebook has no effect on the bad result. Also, setting `cache=False` only on `function1` also has no effect. What does work is setting `cache=False` on all njit'ted functions, then restarting the kernel, then rerunning.

I believe that LLVM is probably inlining some of the called functions and then never checking them again.

I looked in the source and discovered there is a method that returns the cache object `numba.caching.NullCache()`, instantiated a cache object and ran the following:

```
cache = numba.caching.NullCache()
cache.flush()
```

Unfortunately that appears to have no effect.

Is there a numba environment setting, or another way I can manually clear all cached functions within a conda env? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

I am running numba 0.33 with Anaconda Python 3.6 on Mac OS X 10.12.3.

Comment: Update: killing all of the files in the `__pycache__` directory numba uses *does* seem to work. Not sure if there is a better way, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I "solved" this with a hack solution after seeing Josh's answer, by creating a utility in the project method to kill off the cache.

There is probably a better way, but this works. I'm leaving the question open in case someone has a less hacky way of doing this.

```
import os


def kill_files(folder):
    for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print("failed on filepath: %s" % file_path)


def kill_numba_cache():

    root_folder = os.path.realpath(__file__ + "/../../")

    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root_folder):
        for dirname in dirnames:
            if dirname == "__pycache__":
                try:
                    kill_files(root + "/" + dirname)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("failed on %s", root)
```

Comment: A couple years later, I haven't found a better way and I'm still using the above function without issue, so I'm marking it as the correct one. Anyone from the numba project who has a better way, let me know!

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit of a hack, but it's something I've used before. If you put this function in the top-level of where your numba functions are (for this example, in `testfile`), it should recompile everything:

```
import inspect
import sys

def recompile_nb_code():
    this_module = sys.modules[__name__]
    module_members = inspect.getmembers(this_module)

    for member_name, member in module_members:
        if hasattr(member, 'recompile') and hasattr(member, 'inspect_llvm'):
            member.recompile()
```

and then call it from your jupyter notebook when you want to force a recompile. The caveat is that it only works on files in the module where this function is located and their dependencies. There might be another way to generalize it.

Comment: Thanks Josh. It didn't quite work for me because I have a large project with a lot of files and packages. But upvoted, because I your this idea to solve it with another "hack" solution, which I put below.

Answer (score 1):

The official document of `Numba` recommends to remove the cache directory for clearing the cache [[link]](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.48.0/developer/caching.html#cache-clearing).

The Numba cache is saved in these four directories [[link]](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.48.0/reference/envvars.html#envvar-NUMBA_CACHE_DIR):

- `numba.config.CACHE_DIR`
- `__pycache__`
- `numba.misc.appdirs.user_cache_dir()`
- `IPython.paths.get_ipython_cache_dir()`

It is possible to find the Numba cache by searching `*.nbi` files [[link]](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.48.0/developer/caching.html#the-implementation).

---

I personally use the following two codes. The former one is referenced from [Python3 project remove __pycache__ folders and .pyc files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991015/python3-project-remove-pycache-folders-and-pyc-files).

```
import pathlib
import shutil

_ = [shutil.rmtree(p) for p in pathlib.Path('.').rglob('__pycache__')]
```

```
import IPython
import shutil

path_parent = IPython.paths.get_ipython_cache_dir()
path_child = os.path.join(path_parent, 'numba_cache')

if path_parent:
    if os.path.isdir(path_child):
        shutil.rmtree(path_child)
```

Comment: These are exactly the directories to search in! Finally found in the `__pycache__` directory at the same level.