# python numba compiled functions import very slow

Tags: python, python-import, numba

I'm using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/index.html) to develop my package, and actually can get times of speed-ups in calculations. Now I'm facing the problem that, when I run my package in command line using

```
python my_package_name.py
```

Many times are spent during importing. To demonstrate this, I used `-X importtime` for testing:

```
python -X importtime test_my_package.py
```

The results are:

```
import time: self [us] | cumulative | imported package
...
import time:      2422 |       3620 |               numpy.core._multiarray_umath
import time:       425 |        425 |                   numpy.compat._inspect
import time:        62 |         62 |                       errno
import time:       439 |        439 |                         urllib
import time:      1199 |       1638 |                       urllib.parse
import time:      1036 |       2735 |                     pathlib
...
import time:      1408 |       2748 |                     pickle
...
import time:     15060 |      24697 |           numpy.core._add_newdocs_scalars
...
import time:      4627 |     111112 |       numpy
...
import time:      1043 |      31561 |           numba.core.config
...
import time:      1111 |       5296 |                 numba.core.errors
import time:       434 |       5729 |               numba.core.types.common
import time:       566 |        566 |                   numba.core.typeconv.castgraph
import time:       379 |        944 |                 numba.core.typeconv
import time:       331 |        331 |                   numba.core.consts
import time:      1104 |       1435 |                 numba.core.ir
import time:      1083 |       3461 |               numba.core.types.misc
import time:      1293 |      10483 |             numba.core.types.containers
import time:      2129 |       2129 |               logging
import time:      1775 |       3904 |             numba.core.types.functions
...
import time:      9340 |       9340 |             scipy._distributor_init
import time:      1915 |       1915 |             scipy._lib._pep440
import time:       562 |        562 |               scipy._lib._ccallback_c
import time:       952 |       1513 |             scipy._lib._ccallback
import time:      2882 |      17989 |           scipy
import time:      3957 |     211268 |         numba
...
import time:  13506351 |   13834005 |       my_package.utilities
...
import time:   3029710 |    3029710 |       my_package.extract_features
import time:   4805845 |    4805845 |       my_package.fast_annotate_spectrum
...
import time:    345628 |     345628 |         my_package.modification_correction
...
import time:   3769461 |    3769461 |             my_package.xxx.fast_annotate_spectrum
...
import time:   4831766 |    4847170 |               my_package.xxx.utilities
...
import time:   9825949 |    9825949 |             my_package.machinelearning.utilities
...
import time:     55041 |     102863 |                                   scipy.stats._continuous_distns
...
import time:   1178353 |   11814805 |           my_package.machinelearning.randomforest
...
import time:   2767857 |    2767857 |       my_package.retrieval_utilities
```

The list is really long (>1300 lines), so I removed those with small importing times, but kept some times when importing `numba`, `numpy` and `scipy` with relatively large times as benchmarks. Obviously, the importing times for the modules in `my_package` are significantly large, even more than **`10 sec`** (*i.e.*, `my_package.utilities`). These modules contain all functions I implemented for calculations which are accelerated using `numba.njit`, *i.e.*, with decolarator `@numba.njit`.

As importing all other modules are quite normal comparing to importing the Python's builtin modules, I suspect that the large importing time is due to importing those functions for `numba` compilation (by `@numba.njit`). Actually, when I commented out some `@numba.njit` decolators in module `my_package.utilities` to make them normal python functions, the importing time is reduced dramatically:

```
import time:   1921836 |    2647152 |       my_package.utilities
```

Any way I can improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the `njit` functions:

```
@numba.njit(cache=True)
```

Which will reload the compiled functions the next time you run your program

*however it can get a bit tricky to delete the cached functions if you need to make a change*

Comment: Great! Thanks. Can you elaborate more about `however it can get a bit tricky to delete the cached functions if you need to make a change`?

Comment: @Elkan The cached files are hidden away in your computer, probably in the generated `__pycache__` folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131691/how-to-clear-cache-or-force-recompilation-in-numba

Comment: I read a bit the doc in `numba` about the cache, if I change the souce code, will it be updated in the saved cache? Or I have to remove previous cache file and re-compile?

Comment: @Elksn I believe you need to delete the cache.

Comment: If you change the source code, you do not actually need to delete the cache.