# Rename apps for a minimal project

Tags: python, django

I'd like to rename myapp from `block` to `article`

1. change the app directory name from block to article
2. amend the `installed apps` in setting.py
3. amend it in `app.py`
4. delete migrations and make new

When I try to login admin site, it report

```
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'article'
```

I found multiple answer to this question, but they are complicated than I simply re-start a new project.

Is it possible a straight-forwards solution.

The error report:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 24, 2018 - 07:25:48
Django version 1.11.13, using settings 'forum.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8001/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x110fff048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'article'
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x105510048>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 251, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/ll_forum/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'article'
```

The project file structure is:

```
In [16]: ! tree -L 2
.
├── article
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── forum
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── ll_forum
│   ├── bin
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   ├── pyvenv.cfg
│   └── share
└── manage.py

14 directories, 15 files
```

The installed apps in setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #my apps
    "article"
]
```

Comment: show full error trace, please.

Comment: some residual left of old app, need more information to figure out.

Comment: try to remove all `pyc` [remove-pycache-folders-and-pyc-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991015/python3-project-remove-pycache-folders-and-pyc-files)

Comment: `delete migrations and make new` Did  you purge database from tables?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408131/3872976

Comment: You can either create a file named apps.py and set a different name in name attribute as follows -

from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'new name'
    verbose_name = "new verbose name"

Comment: it works, could you please post it to the answer. @GauravTomer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a file named -`'apps.py'` in your app directory and set a different name in `'name'` attribute for your app by inheriting django's `'AppConfig'` class as follows -

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppNameConfig(AppConfig): 
    name = 'new name'
    verbose_name = "new verbose name"
```