# How to delete all __pycache__ folders in directory tree

Tags: python

During my simulation, Python creates folders named `__pycache__`. Not just one, but many. The `__pycache__`-folders are almost always created next to the modules that are executed.

But these modules are scattered in my directory. The main folder is called `LPG` and has a lot of subfolders, which in turn have further subfolders. The `__pycache__`-folders can occur at all possible places.

At the end of my simulation I would like to clean up and delete all folders named `__pycache__` within the `LPG`-tree.

What is the best way to do this?

Currently, I am calling the function below on simulation end (also on simulation start). However, that is a bit annoying since I specifically have to write down every Path where a `__pycache__`-folder might occur.

```
def clearCache():
    """
    Removes generic `__pycache__` .

    The `__pycache__` files are automatically created by python during the simulation.
    This function removes the generic files on simulation start and simulation end.
    """
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(Path(f"{PATH_to_folder_X}/__pycache__"))
    except:
        pass

    try:
        shutil.rmtree(Path(f"{PATH_to_folder_Y}/__pycache__"))
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991015/python3-project-remove-pycache-folders-and-pyc-files) question seems to be similar, but there is a difference: I would like my script to remove the folders itself in the end, not manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple solution if you already know where the `__pycache__` folders are just try the following

```
import shutil
import os

def clearCache():
    """
    Removes generic `__pycache__` .

    The `__pycache__` files are automatically created by python during the simulation.
    This function removes the genric files on simulation start and simulation end.
    """
    path = 'C:/Users/Yours/Desktop/LPG'
    try:
       for all in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path + all):
            if all == '__pycache__':
                shutil.rmtree(path + all, ignore_errors=False) 
    except:
        pass
clearCache()
```

Just simple you can still modify the path to the actually your path is.
And if you want the script to penetrate into the subdirectories to remove the pycache folders just check the following

### Example

```
import shutil
import os

path = 'C:/Users/Yours/Desktop/LPG'
for directories, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
    if os.path.isdir(directories):
        if directories[::-1][:11][::-1] == '__pycache__':
                        shutil.rmtree(directories)
```

Comment: Is there some reason I'm missing for using `directories[::-1][:11][::-1]` instead of just `directories[-11:]` or `directories.endswith()`?

Comment: you can use `endswith()` instead of indexing and striding

Answer (score 15):

This will remove all *.pyc files and **pycache** directories recursively in the current directory:

- with python:

```py
import os

os.popen('find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf')
```

- or manually with terminal or cmd:

```sh
find . | grep -E "(__pycache__|\.pyc|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: It works well. Well done!

Answer (score 6):

Bit of a frame challenge here: If you don't want the bytecode caches, the best solution is to not generate them in the first place. If you always delete them after every run, they're worse than useless. Either:

1. Invoke `python`/`python3` with the `-B` option (affects that single launch), or...
2. Set the `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment variable to affect all Python launches until it's unset, e.g. in `bash`, `export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1`

This does need to be set *before* the Python script is launched, so perhaps wrap your script with a simple `bash` script or the like that invokes the real Python script with the appropriate switch/environment set up.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but that is not an option. I'll send the simulator to someone else and I don't want that person to do any big changes

Comment: @maxischl: That's why I suggest the wrapper script; a three line (or less) wrapper script can remove the need for manual tweaks.

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is the proper and solid solution, but in this case I'll rather stick to the quick and dirty version

Answer (score 4):

Another simple solution is available if you have access to a Command-Line Interface and the [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) utility:

```
find . -type d -name __pycache__
```

as you will ask in plain language, it `find`s in the current folder (`.`) directories (`-type d`) that exactly match your pattern `-name __pycache__`. You can use this to identify where these folders are and then  to delete them:

```
find . -type d -name __pycache__ -exec rm -r {} \;
```

the huge advantage of this solution is that it transfers to other tasks easily (finding `*.pyc` files?) and has become an everyday tool for me.

Comment: the `-f` in this answer (and Milovan's) seems overkill and potentially dangerous if somebody makes a typo. Under what circumstances would `__pycache__` directories be protected?

Comment: completly right, @craq - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete any folders from any directory, use this function.
By default, it would start deleting from current directory and recursively goes in every sub-directories

```py
import os
import shutil


def remove_dirs(curr_dir='./', del_dirs=['temp_folder', '__pycache__']):
    for del_dir in del_dirs:
        if del_dir in os.listdir(curr_dir):
            shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(curr_dir, del_dir))

    for dir in os.listdir(curr_dir):
        dir = os.path.join(curr_dir, dir)
        if os.path.isdir(dir):
            self.remove_dirs(dir, del_dirs)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `os` with `glob` like this:

```
import os, glob

in_dir = "/path/to/your/folder"

pattern = ['__pycache__']

for p in pattern:
    [os.remove(x) for x in glob.iglob(os.path.join(in_dir, "**", p), recursive=True)]
```

Comment: That results in a `PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: ...`

Comment: In some specific moments we get some errors. Even though it work in some cases, sometimes it doesn't `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '../game/gui/__pycache__'`