# Removing pycache files from Django project

Tags: python, django

Recently I have tried cloning my production code to a different pc. Then I have connected my project to a blank DB and run the command `python manage.py makemigrations` and after that, I can see that my migrations folder was updated with some `__pycache__` files.
URL: /folder/app/migrations/pycache
I know that the migrations files are very important but here the problem is the production DB contains data and the DB in that different PC is empty. I think if I push these `__pycache__` files to the production it might create conflict.

My idea is not to push these pycache files(/folder/app/migrations/pycache) into my production environment and ignore them using the gitignore(as I am using git for version control).

Am I doing the right thing?

and Should/can I gitignore all the `__pycache__` files from the project.

Comment: Did you mean `__pycache__` and not just `pycache`?

Comment: @bdbd yes i meant `__pycache__`

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60954832/6759844) for a way to delete those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below line in your `.gitignore` file to avoid Byte Compiled File in Python

```
**/__pycache__
*.pyc
```

Please make sure that your folders not already tracked.

Comment: will removing/not including `__pycache__` files in the codebase can create errors?

Comment: Not at all. It will not create any kind of issue.