# How to use tweepy python library as aws lambda layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, tweepy

I am following this instructions to create an AWS Lambda layer:

```
mkdir my-lambda-layer && cd my-lambda-layer
mkdir -p aws-layer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
pip3 install tweepy --target aws-layer/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages
cd aws-layer
```

I zip then the folder "python" (`zip -r tweepy_layer.zip python/`) and upload it to s3. This is what I see when I unzip the folder to double check:

[image]
Unfortunately, I still get the following error though the pass should be the same as in the [docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) I tried both from MacOs and Ubuntu though I do not think this should play a role for this particular library.

[image]

Comment: Is the library in the zip file?

Comment: yes - I see tweepy among site-packages

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the problem turned out to be the **cache.** Yes, all those `__pycache__` and `.pyc` files. Thanks to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991015/python3-project-remove-pycache-folders-and-pyc-files) I cleared the cache after installing the libraries by doing

```
pip3 install pyclean
pyclean .
```

After cleaning the cache, re-doing the zip and uploading it to s3 the lambda setup works perfectly:

[image]