# Can I choose where python's cached *.pyc files are created and stored?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a followup to the earlier [*What is __pycache__?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024) question.

Is there a way to tell `python-3.x` to always put its `__pycache__` directory (or the `*.pyc` files it contains) in some designated place. E.g. by setting some environment variable like `PYCACHEDIR=${HOME}/bin/python-cache`?

For the record, I am using Mac OS X.10.3 & python3 installed with brew.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing anyway? If you just want to remove them, you can create a script that recursively deletes all those files/directories in your folder and subfolders. I am not seeing why you should need to put those files in another directory...please enlighten me!

Comment: Since you need to know, the name pycache sounds exactly like something really gross in our local slang.  And I like the way many things in unix-like systems can be customized by the user.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing.  I have a case where the directories with the source files are not writable, and want to relocate the pycache so that all users can benefit from the cache without having write access to the actual python source file directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
As of 3.8 it is now possible:  you can control the base location by using [`PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX=path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX), [`-X pycache_prefix=path`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPYCACHEPREFIX), or [`sys.pycache_prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.pycache_prefix).

---

*Answer prior to 3.8*:

No, you cannot.  The `__pycache__` directory is where Python will look for pre-compiled files that match the requested `.py` file, and its location is not negotiable.