# Hiding __pycache__ on Linux

Tags: linux, python-3.x

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/what-is-pycache) which explains what `__pycache__` is and how to hide it on OSX and Windows.

I'm looking for an equivalent for Linux.

I already have it in my `.gitignore` for when I push it, but I often use `tree` to get an overview of my project directories, and it looks messy to see the `__pycache__` directories everywhere.

Comment: hide it or don't write it completely?

Comment: @Jim I didn't know you could tell python to not write them at all. Ideally I would just like to not have them displayed in my directory listing. How would I prevent python from writing them completely?

Comment: set `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1` in your `/etc/environment` file. If you're running from a IDE, it probably also offers a way to set default flags for python everytime it executes, you could add `-B` to that so it uses it every time.