# What type files should be put into .gitignore file in Django project

Tags: python, django, git, gitignore

From my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342829/whats-the-pycache-in-django-project?noredirect=1#comment81637886_47342829), I know the `__pycache__` should be put into the `.gitignore` when I use git.

And in the other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/what-is-pycache?answertab=votes#tab-top) I saw, there are also `.pyc` and `.pyo` files.

whether them should all be put into the `.gitignore` file?

Can we summarize in the Python/Django project, what files should be put into `. gitignore` file?

Comment: It's going to be different for Python projects in general versus Django projects. General rule: things that are generated should go into `.gitignore`. I'd suggest finding some Python and Django projects on GitHub and seeing what they have in their `.gitignore`s. Also note that if you add `__pycache__/`, you don't need to add `*.pyc` and `*.pyo` unless your project runs on Python 2.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a popular web service called [Gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) that help developers generate gitignore files for popular framework and languages. You can see the Django one [here](https://www.gitignore.io/api/django).

```
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
media
```

On top of that I would also recommend you to ignore things environment items such as virtualenv, or .env files that are related to the local environment that the code is being run from. This also allow you to store passwords and secrets in environment files, and keep them out of your git repo.

```
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/
```

Lastly I would also add the django `static` folder to the list of files to ignore since it is collected with `collectstatic` whenever you deploy your code.