# Using Python 3 and __pycache__

Tags: python

I am having issues understanding the **pycache** folder. Running some simple scripts today I noticed my **pycache** folder was created and had the .pyc file for ONE of the two scripts I was running. Why not .pyc files for both. This is in Liunux, using the #! /user/bin/python3 line at the top of my scripts so I can run the simple by typing ./script_name. Just to ensure I was not confused, I deleted the **pycache** folder and ran both scripts again, but now no **pycache** folder was created. I also ran them as python3 my_scripts, still no **pycache** folder is getting created. Can someone explain to me how this works, or point me to a GOOD article explaining this. I know why it gets created, but I dont know why it si sometimes not even if I dont use flags or env vars to suppress it's creation. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_pycache\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869024/what-is-pycache)

Comment: Nope, dont think so. I know what the __pycache__ folder is for, what I dont understand is why it is sometimes created and sometimes not. I do know that you can use flags or ENV vars to make python not create it, but I am not using those.

Comment: `__pycache__` is created when you import the file (in another script), not when you run it.

Comment: myrmica, thanks, I just ran some quick tests and you are absolutely correct. That was mention in the post that Rajen pointed me to, but there was conflicting responses. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mikeg Also, you will get a `.pyc` file when you run the file as a module from command line, e.g. `python3 -m name`. (as opposed to `python3 name.py`)