# __pycache__ showing up in .git/refs/remotes/origin

Tags: python, git

I had an issue where an Azure DevOps pipeline stopped working, and it turned out to be because there was a ref `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc` which was "broken" (and clearly shouldn't have existed in the first place). So I logged into the server, deleted that `__pycache__`  directory, and the pipeline started working again as expected.

Now, I just tried switching branches on my local, and I got the same error:

```bash
$ git fetch --all --prune
Fetching origin
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc': unable to resolve reference 'refs/remotes/origin/feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc': reference broken
error: could not remove reference refs/remotes/origin/feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc
```

I'm quite puzzled at how this came to be. Has anyone seen this before? Is this potentially an issue where someone accidentally created a new branch like `git checkout -b feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc`? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm quite puzzled at how this came to be.

Git stores names—branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and the like—in a [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database) where the full name, e.g., `refs/heads/main`, is the key, and the value is a hash ID.  OK, but what does this have to do with anything? Well, the actual *implementation* of this key-value database is pretty sleazy, at the moment:

- sometimes the name-value pair consist of a line (perhaps with an auxiliary line added) in a *file* named `.git/packed-refs`;
- sometimes the value is stored in a plain-text file (no auxiliary line added) that is stored in a *directory* within `.git/refs`, with the directory name made up of the components of the reference (with the redundant `refs/` elided).

Sometimes it's even in both locations, although this means that the "unpacked" file ref overrides the packed one as it's presumed to be newer.

So *this* means that if a branch named `feature/foo` exists, `.git/refs/heads/feature/` *might* exist.  Or it might not!

OK, but so what?  Well, *if* that directory does exist *and* you run a Python program *and* Python loads a file named `app.py` and byte-compiles it to a `.pyc` file (and you're using Python3), the *python byte-compiler* might *write the `.pyc` file* to a file named `__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc`.<sup>1</sup>  Python will then use this byte-compiled file to load and run things.

But once *Python* has done that, *Git* will think that `.git/refs/heads/feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc` is a valid ref and therefore there is a branch named `feature/__pycache__/app.cpython-310.pyc`.  Unfortunately, its hash ID is garbage.

The same sort of thing can happen with a remote-tracking name: the only difference is that the directory in question will begin with `.git/refs/remotes/origin/feature/`.  In both cases, Git thinks the name is valid, but the value—the hash ID—is bogus.  This is what causes the failure to "lock" the "broken" reference.<sup>2</sup>

The real question, then, is: **What caused a running Python program to drop a `__pycache__` file into a subdirectory of your Git repository?**  The location of the `__pycache__` directory is supposed to be the same as the location of the loaded `.py` file, which would suggest that something wrote an `app.py` file inside this internal Git repository `.git/refs/` directory, which would be bad (programs should not do that sort of thing: they should generate their temporary files in private temporary directories or `/tmp` or similar).

Other than pointing to [What is __pycache__?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16869024/1256452) and [If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2998215/1256452) I must leave this mystery unsolved at this point, since I have no idea what created this `app.py` file in the first place.

---

<sup>1</sup>The compiled file may end with `.pyo` if byte-code-optimization is turned on.  Python2 writes these files next to the `.py` files, rather than in a `__pycache__` directory.  The `cpython-310` part in the middle means you're using CPython version 3.10; this version number insertion doesn't occur in some (older) versions of Python.

<sup>2</sup>The act of "locking" a ref in this case consists of creating a file whose name ends in `.lock` and is otherwise the same as the full ref file name.  This file will be used to hold the new value, and an atomic `rename` operation will be used to swap the file into place to update and unlock the ref.  All of this depends heavily on POSIX file semantics, which is one of the numerous reasons one should not put a `.git` repository into cloud-managed software folders, which don't obey POSIX file semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I should update with an answer:

I had a script for validating commits, testing whether files compiled and doing various linty things. This script was apparently iterating over the `.git` directory and trying to compile a (perhaps poorly named) `refs/heads/feature/app.py` branch. Fixed by deleting the `__pycache__` directory and ensuring the validation script skipped over the `.git` directory :)