# Is it bad coding practice to bundle modified modules?

Tags: python

Sometimes when I'm working in a large package, I'll find that there's behavior that's very difficult to work around in one of the dependencies, and sometimes the only way to implement a solution and move on is to alter a module in the dependency and wait for a fix or a new feature from the developers.  Just to make this more concrete, imagine the workaround is in matplotlib.legend.py.  Here's where how my project might be packaged:

```
myproject
   bundled
       legend.py
   a.py
   b.py
   c.py
```

And until a new version of matplotlib is released that fixes some bug or implements some feature, I just make calls like:

```
from bundled.legend import X,Y,Z
```

Obviously this works sometimes, but often I have to bundle several modules to get the behavior.

Sometimes doing this is the only way I can move forward on a project, but I don't know how other engineers would react to this practice.  Is this an acceptable practice in `python`?  A lot of times it's not just workarounds that motivate this, but customization or adding some features particular to `myproject` that are deep into the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not always work as you expect. Imagine the following case.

1. User installs very old version of legend.
2. User install your package with a newer bundles version of legend

Now, in your code, you do

```
from bundled.legend import X
```

BUT, in legend.x is says

```
from legend import Y
```

It could import Y from the old version of legend the user installed.

You might want to take a look at: [Embedding a Python library in my own package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812614/embedding-a-python-library-in-my-own-package)

Comment: Thank you, these are exactly the kinds of issues I was trying to anticipate.  Thanks for the link.