# How to install modules from a package?

Tags: python, installation, module

For installing python packages, is there a way to only install the specific modules I need (plus dependencies) into the virtual environment?

For example, I import the following in my code

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
```

I only need `ARIMA` (and dependencies), and won't need the complete `statsmodels` library.

How do I accomplish that?

Rationale:

- I am trying to zip up the packages and deploy to AWS lambda. However, I am exceeding the 50MB file size limit.
- If there is a way to install only the modules I need from the packages, I can reduce the file size.

Comment: I don't think it's possible since when installing library or etc actually we're installing the complete `.whl` in depth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a horrible brute-force approach. I hope someone gives you a better answer!

Assuming the source you want to install is public, its licensing allows this kind of use, and you are willing to deal with the hassle, I imagine you could:

- copy the source
- remove anything unused by your required module
- place that module's source inside your package, and wire it up from there. (This answer proposes [a reasonable file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18812776/9872253) for vendored software)

Alternately, if the assumptions above hold but you prefer not to vendor directly within your software, you could probably:

- copy the source (e.g. fork the repo)
- remove anything not used by your required module, making sure to leave a working python package
- [use `pip`](https://medium.com/underdog-io-engineering/vendoring-python-dependencies-with-pip-b9eb6078b9c0) or your environment's native dependency management tools to download and install your package in the virtual env.

Please note that both of these approaches will expose you to a number of risks, including but not limited to:

- breaking the module: what happens to your project if you accidentally created a logical or security flaw?
- loss of currency: how do you plan to keep your new mini-package up to date?
- liability: Does the vendored software's license allow this kind of use? Are you adequately protected if there is something wrong with the software you have modified?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Very practical and outlines all the risks.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Yi. Please upvote if you found the answer useful, and consider accepting it if you believe it to be the best correct/viable answer.

Comment: I would love to, and I did! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet, so it doesn't show.

Comment: Absolutely no pressure to accept this answer, but as the asker you have the privilege accept an answer regardless your rep. It will give you +2, and you can change the accepted answer later if you get a better one. 

Here's how: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work