# Does the interpreter compile python scripts?

Tags: python, compilation, interpreter

I wrote a script, say, `samplescript.py`. All I can recall doing with, other than editing it, is running it through the command-line python interpreter.

Later, I found a `samplescript.pyc` file. Does running a script through the interpreter always invoke the compilation of the script?

Comment: Yes. It compiles it. How else should it know what to do?

Comment: The next time you run the script, your computer can use the `.pyc` file instead of re-compiling.  A new `.pyc` file gets generated if the `.py` file changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you execute your code, python creates a compiled pyc file. This file is the one executed in posterior runs if you do not modify your code

From [here](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/node43.html):

> As an important speed-up of the start-up time for short programs that
>   use a lot of standard modules, if a file called "spam.pyc" exists in
>   the directory where "spam.py" is found, this is assumed to contain an
>   already-``byte-compiled'' version of the module spam. The modification
>   time of the version of "spam.py" used to create "spam.pyc" is recorded
>   in "spam.pyc", and the file is ignored if these don't match.
>
> Normally, you don't need to do anything to create the "spam.pyc" file.
>   Whenever "spam.py" is successfully compiled, an attempt is made to
>   write the compiled version to "spam.pyc". It is not an error if this
>   attempt fails; if for any reason the file is not written completely,
>   the resulting "spam.pyc" file will be recognized as invalid and thus
>   ignored later. The contents of the "spam.pyc" file is platform
>   independent, so a Python module directory can be shared by machines of
>   different architectures.