# Python 3.4.2 on Sublime text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I've installed Python 3.4.2 and Sublime text 3 on my Mac. When I go to build a simple program all I get is a .pyc file being created. It creates it on my desktop and I have no idea why.

I have noted the post from a few years ago suggesting that the full path to python 3 needs to be provided so that I can use Sublime text 3. I tried the two listed solutions with the last being the following

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3 $file",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
}
```

I go back to run my simple

```
print ("hello someone")
```

and it completes the task without showing "Hello someone". I removed my test file by accident and it threw up a message about Python 2.7.

Comment: What's a PYC file: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2998215/3001761