# Python Compile file(.pyc) generated even after errors in code-why?

Tags: python, python-2.7, compilation

I have the below code in a file **a1.py**

```
fff
def test(arg):
        print 'sid'
        print arg
        print 'sid2'
test()
```

The above code contains 2 errors:

1. fff does not exist and is still being asked to print
2. Arguments are not passed in test()

Now i write an another file **b1.py**
In that file the code is:

```
import a1
print 'b1 execution done'
```

Que 1: I executed b1.py and a1.pyc file is generated. Why ? There is a syntax error.pyc file should not have been generated?

Que2: Explain in laymen terms what is pyc file and what role does it play?

Que3: Why is pyc file generated even if a1.py has errors ?(e.g. argument not being passed)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files)

Comment: .pyc files are compiled version of your source.  If you delete them they get recreated, so that the next time your program runs, it can just use the .pyc file.  I believe Q3 would be a runtime error, and that hasn't happened yet

Comment: but i am trying to access a variable 'fff' which does not exist.This should have been a compile time error? Correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Python automatically compiles your script to compiled code, so called byte code, before running it. When a module is imported for the first time, or when the source is more recent than the current compiled file, a .pyc file containing the compiled code will usually be created in the same directory as the .py file.