# pyc got checked into my git project by coworker, how comes?

Tags: python, git, intellij-idea

i've been working with the python project before and never submitted a pyc file. Not sure as to why.

I am using intellij, maybe it automatically ignores those files and doesn't display them?

maybe I am not using CPython? python --version spits out to me

`Python 3.6.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.`

Comment: you can remove them add it to .gitignore then commit it :)

Answer (score 2):

[If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files)

Pyc files will be created when you import (and use) a python module. You might want to add an entry into .gitignore to ignore these files, while clearing all pyc files from your project.

Answer (score 1):

pyc files are ignored by default by git. Unless instructed otherwise, cf. [this post](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files) and [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Note the developer can change it in his own workspace. If the pyc are indeed ignored, the only way to overcome the rule is a `git add —force`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was that I *never* had the issue of committing a pyc file. Now I added it to gitignore and what not, but why did *I* never commit it before?

turns out... intellij idea does completely ignore pyc files... I cannot even create a pyc file in the project manually. So maybe that is why.