# file path error in python

Tags: python

I want to generate dynamically the name of a yaml file based on the name of a python script. Generally this is my naming convention:

> if test name is test_action_01.py
>
> then the yaml file name should be action_01.yml

So to acheive that I have these two lines in the python script (inside test_action_01.py) :

```
    file_name = (os.path.basename(__file__).replace("test_", "")).replace(".py", ".yml")
    pb_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '../playbooks', file_name))
    with open(pb_path, 'r') as f:
        pb = yaml.load(f)
```

When I run the script I get this strange error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_create_01.py", line 22, in setUp
    with open(pb_path, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/jenkins/workspace/aws-s3-tests/aws-s3/playbooks/create_01.ymlc'
```

I don't understand from where the extra "c" character somes from ?
I'm using `Python2.7`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have the `test_action_01.pyc` file that contains ( byte code ) , you need to check, maybe:

```
if not os.path.basename(__file__).endswith('c'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[cPython compiles its code to bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files). This bytecode is what gets executed and it is stored in a `*.pyc` file, which allows this to be cached. So when you run your script, `__file__` is actually `test_action_01.pyc`.

You can call `pb_path.rstrip('c')` to get rid of whether or not it is there (if there is nothing to remove, `rstrip` just returns the input string).