# Trouble with explicit relative import within package

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import

I am running into a very frustrating syntax error that is appearing in the following scenario:

```
package
    __init__.py
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

The `__init__.py` contains the following import:

```
from . import module1
```

`module1.py` contains the following import:

```
from . import module2
```

I get a syntax error right when it hits the explicit relative import in `module1.py`, so it would seem that the import in `__init__.py` is working correctly.

Earlier, I had things setup where I was importing `module1.py` like this:

```
from package import module1
```

Which worked correctly, so I am very confused as to why I am getting this error...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the traceback?

Comment: Have you tried deleting any compiled files (those with file extension `*.pyc`; more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2998228/9225671)) ? Sometimes they do not get renewed and contain old versions that do not match your current code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going back to the previous working state and rewrote from there. It seems like the issue disappeared, so at least I am able to move forward, but I unfortunately don't know what caused it.

During the rewrite, I did run into a similar issue (Syntax Error) that had to do with the way I was attempting to import functions from a module within the package like so:

```
from . import module.function as name # causes syntax error

from .module import function as name # seems to work correctly
```

It seems like that might have been involved, but that was not part of the code when I initially posted this question, so I am unsure if it is relevent...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `import module1` and `import module2`? All 3 files are in the same directory.

Comment: That should work as well, technically, since this is Python 2. However, I am trying to avoid implicit relative imports.