# what is pycache folder in flask python?

Tags: python, pyc

I am working on a flask project.

and there is `__pycache__` file under app> main  with `.pyc` files.

What are these for?

### and when I try to click on the `.pyc` file , it says `the file is not displayed in the editor becuase it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.`  what are the ways to open this file and see what is inside? Thank you.

Edit:
I found what this file is for in other website

At the time when you run a program in python, the interpreter compiles it to bytecode first and after compilation interpreter stores it in the **pycache** folder. So when you look in there you will find a bunch of files sharing the names of the .py files in your project's folder, you will see that their extensions will be either .pyc or .pyo. These files are bytecode-compiled and optimized bytecode-compiled versions of your program's files, respectively.

**pycache** makes your program to start a little faster. When your scripts change, they will be recompiled, and if you delete the files or the whole folder and run your program again, they will reappear (unless you specifically suppress that behavior)

https://intellipaat.com/community/4278/what-is-pycache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.pyc` files are compiled Python files written by the Python interpreter. [Read here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/ddg#2998544)