# How to delete all my pycache folders from an Anaconda installation of Python?

Tags: python

I have P`ython 3.8` installed via `Anaconda`. I am running a Python script from the command line and I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: bad magic number in 'myscript': b'B\r\r\n'
```

Following some research online, I came across a post where the author stated that the solution is to run the following lines to clear the cache folders:

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

Since I'm new to Python, I would like some help on the following:

(1) Where do I run that command?

As I mentioned above, I installed Python using Anaconda. So, do I just need to get into the following path in my command prompt (C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3) and run the codes from there?

(2) Is it safe to delete all the "pyc" folders?

Comment: You would run that command from a UNIX/Linux-style command line prompt. If you're on Windows, a basic installation of Cygwin or Git Bash should work. Run it from your `site-packages` directory.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. Do I still need to install Cygwin or GitBash to run it?

Comment: Yes. The `find` utility is only available there.

Comment: Thanks. that was helpful. Can you post as answer and I'll vote accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command needs to be run from a UNIX-ish command line - something like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or [Git bash](https://git-scm.com/) on Windows.

Using Cygwin, you should be able to run something along the lines of

```sh
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/Anaconda/Lib/site-packages # omit /cygdrive if using Git bash
```

I don't use Anaconda and I'm not sure what the exact file path is, so you should confirm it using Windows explorer. There may be a Python version somewhere in there.

Once you're in the proper `site-packages` directory, you can run

```sh
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

and you should be all set.

In response to your second question, yes, it is safe to delete `.pyc` files. Your imports will just take a little longer to run the next time you use them, as they'll be recreating their respective `.pyc` files from scratch.

See [If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files) (the second answer, specifically) for an explanation of what `.pyc` files are.