# My python program works faster before compiling it

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hello I have a program that I wrote. It reads en excel file and inserts it into sqlite. It is like a CLI. It works very well on terminal. But after I compile it with pyinstaller It took 1m20s to read and write 16 rows of excel file. On VSCode (or without compiling it) it takes few seconds.

Is it about pyinstaller? I tried with and without --onefile.

Since it has other functions It is relatively large to post here.

Comment: Executables compiled with `--onefile` are slower (see the [doc](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file)). I guess loading dependencies takes a while on startup.

Comment: Have you create a virtual environment for the specific script ? If not you may have put to your `one file` many unnecessary packages! what's the size of the executable ?

Comment: I've seen and read about `--onefile`starting slower. But my problem is it works slower. Starting delay is not my concern at the moment :) The program reads an excel file with 16 rows and 1 word on each row. Checks if that word exists in sqlite database if not  performs an insert operation. This takes almost 1.5 minutes with pyinstaller executible. If I run the script on terminal it takes couple seconds.  ps: yes I have an venv :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies probably in a misconception of what using PyInstaller does (and does not) achieve:

PyInstaller does *not* compile your code into anything like optimized machine code that is supposed to run faster than regular Python code (which is what the term "compile" might imply)*. Instead, its purpose is to provide *portability* for your code: PyInstaller wraps up your code together with all the dependencies that are needed to run it into a single folder (default) or file (using PyInstaller's `--onefile` argument). In a sense, it provides a portable minimum Python environment to run your code – see [*What PyInstaller Does and How It Does It*](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html).

Especially with `--onefile`, this means that the bundled code has to be extracted first before it can be run. This, in turn, means that a small snippet of code will be much slower when run from a PyInstaller bundle than when run directly in your Python terminal or IDE, precisely due to this extraction overhead.

*) Yes, it works with bytecode versions of your code (i.e. `*.pyc` files), but these are also produced by your Python terminal or IDE and thus should not make a difference in running time (you can read more on the role of bytecode files in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/)).

Answer (score -1):

The issue is in pyinstaller.
if want run the script directly write script in bash that runs your