# How can I test this github project?

Tags: python, django

[ps-random-combo-generator-github](https://github.com/djrobertjin/ps-random-combo-generator)

Pen Spinning Random Combo Generator, using Django Framework & MySQL.

I am interested in the hobby field of pen spinning. I have no programming knowledge, but I want to test this project. I try different things but eventually I get the same errors. How can I make this project work?

First of all, I installed the latest versions of Python, Django and Mysql-server on my computer.

I am proficient in graphic design and computer use, but since I have no knowledge of programming, I took help from ChatGPT.

I ran the python manage.py runserver command and it froze with the following error.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls' (C:\Users\maco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls_*init*_.py)

Then I heard that the urls.py file contains old commands. (It contains """django 1.9""" information.)

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^combos/', include('randomGen.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I changed the content from this to this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

urlpatterns = [
    path('combos/', include('randomGen.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

But I got the same error again.

I tried to open it with Django 1.9 but I encountered more errors.

I want to try again but I have no way to follow it. Should I try with the old version? Or is a little code editing enough? Frankly, I don't know this.

What I want to achieve is to test the website on my personal computer.

Comment: That code is eight years old. It may have been written for Python 2.x, which is very old. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I tried to try it by installing the latest version of Python and Python 2.7.

Comment: I don't do Python. But I notice that each of the `.py` files there have a corresponding `.pyc` file, which are [compiled bytecode files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files). I think since these are generated they should not have been committed to the repo.

Comment: Hopefully each `.pyc` file is a faithful compiled version of the source code provided, but in theory one of these could do something mean, like delete your Documents folder. So to start with I would delete all of them and try again. Indeed your Python system may recreate them anyway.

Comment: For best safety, I would recommend trying this code in a virtual machine or a container, unless you have a good reason to trust it.