Can't create a python macro in Libre Office Calc
I have read tutorials that explain how to create a python macro :

I added the folders Scripts and python to obtain this :
C:\Users\Myosotis\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python
Then, I created the file break.py where I put a function named test :

{ Code :
from scriptforge import CreateScriptService

def test(args=None)
    doc = CreateScriptService("Calc")
    doc.SetValue("G3","test")
    return None

}
But when I open the popup Macros Python, the folder break is empty :

I'd like to know why, or at least to know where are stored all these "Application macros", so I can have a look at them.
I use Libre Office version 24.2.3.2 (X86_64) on Windows 10.0

Open a PowerShell prompt and execute the script with LibreOffice's python.
chdir "${env:ProgramFiles}\LibreOffice\program\"
./python "C:/Users/U/AppData/Roaming/LibreOffice/4/user/Scripts/python/break.py"

This reveals the error, which as you can see, is due to missing : after the statement.
File "C:/Users/U/AppData/Roaming/LibreOffice/4/user/Scripts/python/break.py", line 3
    def test(args=None)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

On Windows, the "Application" (shared) macro location is typically C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\share\Scripts\python.
If you haven't yet, be sure to try the APSO extension to run python-uno macros. And the tutorial.
For bigger projects, I use pylint to check syntax. Also, I catch and log exceptions, for example:
def log_exceptions(self, func):
    """Decorator method to log uncaught exceptions."""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            self._setup()
            self.logger.exception("Caught exception at top level.")
            # Re-raising is proper coding practice when catching all
            # exceptions, and we do so even though it will probably
            # have no effect, at least during runtime.
            raise

    return wrapper

def _setup(self):
    """Set up a minimalist file logger."""
    raise NotImplementedError()


Thank you so much ! I didn't think python worked as a compiled language when used with Libreoffice.

@Myosotis: LibreOffice comes with CPython on Windows, which gets compiled into an intermediate bytecode form as Java does. However, Java UNO code must be compiled with files such as unoidl.jar in a separate step, while CPython does not require an explicit separate compile step and can even be compiled on-the-fly in a live session. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files.
