# Where to download the open source language of C?

Tags: c, open-source

I want to learn how C is interpreted,

anyone knows where to download it?

Comment: C is not interpreted, it is compiled.
C is not downloaded, it is specified.  Various implementations of a compiler that implements the specification may be downloaded.

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=open+source+c+compiler&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC

Comment: @mark: ditto [google.com](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=open+source+c+compiler)

Comment: @abelenky – Actually, C is translated and then executed. [Interpreters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c) exist.

Comment: Ironic user name you have there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cpp.shtml

I found that in about 10 seconds using Google.  You can too.

Answer (score 2):

A good basic compiler suitable for getting an intro to the subject and including sources is [tinyc](http://bellard.org/tcc/). It is capable of being used in a similar manner as an interpreter, too (unlike GCC et al).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/C

and this:

http://gcc.gnu.org/