# Anyone know of a simple C interpreter written in C#?

Tags: c#, c, interpreter

About 13 years ago I needed a way to script an application I was writing in Borland C++. I found a C interpreter and embedded that in my application. This has been working fine and I have quite a number of scripts.

I now need to rework the app and will do this in C#. Does anyone know of a C interpreter for C#? I have the sources for the original interpreter but I just need to save some time.

**Edit**
Here is an extract from a script:

```
main()
{
   LwSet( "STUFE", "00.00" );
   LwSet( "STATUS", "Warten", "AUS" );
   do
   {
      LwSet( "DEBUG", "OFF" );
      LwSet( "FUNKTION", "Warten auf Start" );
      do
      {
         rc = LwGet( "Event" );
         if( rc == "QUIT" ) {
            ...
```

The LwSet/LwGet calls a functions which I registered with the interpreter and are features of my application.

**Edit2**

Before anyone feels the need to tell me what other language I **should** have used, here is my comment from below:

> At the time, and considering the skills available it was not an annoying choice. Now, 13 years later, a lot of things look a whole lot different! I'm just stuck with a pile of quasi-C scripts which I would like to use without having to convert them all somehow.

Comment: What exactly is that interpreter doing?

Comment: Using C as a scripting language for an application sounds a bit annoying. Couldn't you just C# itself? Or maybe Lua?

Comment: @unwind: maybe he has a lot of LEGACY CODE to support (a lot of C scripts already written/working on his/her application)

Comment: @unwind At the time, and considering the skills available it was not an annoying choice. Now, 13 years later, a lot of things look a whole lot different! I'm just stuck with a pile of quasi-C scripts which I would like to use without having to convert them all somehow.

Comment: or TCL or python or JavaScript or pretty much anything but C

Comment: +1 I think this would be a wonderful thing to get going on the DLR!

Comment: That code snippet is pretty simple, perhaps a simple solution would be to use some regexes (or similar) to convert the c scripts to c# scripts. The example above is 99% c# compatible, all that needs changing is some imports and changing the main() declaration.

Comment: Why do not to use old interpreter by interop?

Comment: I really doubt that what you've got is a C interpreter. It is something "C-like". So, with all your legacy code, you've got no other choice but to use the very same interpreter via interop or porting manually it to C#. No other C interpreter will be able to replace that one.

Answer (score 5):

How about using the same existing C interpreter from C# via interop?

Answer (score 3):

The excellent [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) parser generator has [support for C#](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target).  Its [examples](http://www.antlr.org/download/examples-v3.tar.gz) include a C grammar for C#.

This obviously isn't a full interpreter, but the grammar, lexer and parser would make a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any C interpreter for C# but there is a c# scripting engine that you might be able to use.

http://www.csscript.net/index.html

Comment: -1; sorry, question is pretty explicit - needs a C interpreter

Comment: +1, it's a valid answer.  Close the question as "too localized" if SO users shouldn't be allowed to suggest a better approach.

Comment: I agree with Kieren. The question made it clear he did not want to convert the scripts.

Comment: I gave this answer in case he did not find what he was looking for, at least he has an option to go with. My answer did clearly state that I did not know of any C interpreter.

Comment: @Hans - indeed, at the time of posting he clearly says he has legacy C scripts he doesn't want to convert, and he's looking for a C interpreter.  How can suggesting a C# scripting engine be an answer to that question?  It's the answer to the question, "I want to add scripting/an interpreter to my app for purpose X", but not this one..

Comment: I must say that Alex was the first to provide a *useful* suggestion :-) Even if it isn't exactly what I was looking for it is more helpful than saying how annoying C is!

Comment: I agree that the question was very specific, but if he does not find an answer, are we going to leave him with at least an option. I am just trying to help.

Comment: The idea that SO should cater to the needs of *one* SO user is silly.  This question is going to linked by Google for many years by other programmers that look for a scripting solution.  If they can't see better advice then SO is not useful to them.

Comment: I'd argue (and downvoted) for the same reason: yet another useless Google result for someone searching for "C interpreter written in C#"!.  Also, something that's a 'sideways' suggestion should be a comment, not an answer, no?

Comment: I fear that the desire to have a "SO police" and clean up all the posts and topics may be getting a bit out of control. I, for instance, see no useful purpose of purging posts with slightly off-topic but useful answers. Besides, I was also looking for a C interpreter in .NET, and now I can think of many good uses to the CS-Script linked in the above post, for which I learned for the first time from this very same post. By the way (no offense, just out of curiosity), @KierenJohnstone, if you think this post has no place here, why did not you try flagging it instead of down-voting?

Answer (score 2):

The nearist think I'm aware of is:
http://www.softintegration.com/

Added the following  Link
[Is there an interpreter for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c)

Regards
Friedrich

Comment: I don't think you can easily embed this in a C# application.

Comment: Hm interfacing to C is not to difficult in C# or is it? If interfacing is easy than I can not see the problems. At least I think it would be worth a try....

Comment: AFAIK there's only COM interop, but I doubt their solution is COM compatible

Comment: See http://www.softintegration.com/support/faq/embed.html And that seems to be not much more than passing a opaque pointer around and this works mostly unproblematic I've done that with C# and C shared  libraries before. So it seems this is a very doable way of getting a C/C++ interpreter. Of course YMMV ...

Comment: I think it's a lot of work, but he might not have a choice.

Comment: I don't think so, just see the first example. You compile it into an DLL and use the Pinvoke Services on this function. You just hand over either a file or a string and let it execute the main function for calling the Interpreter. But maybe the other link is more useful? Just call the tcc with a script via System and "let" it interpret whatever there is in the file ;-)