# C Interpreter (Not Compiler)?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, interpreter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an interpreter for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c)

Is there a "C implementation" which acts the same as the "C abstract machine" when executing a C program? That is, a simple *interpreter* for C as it is described in a C standard such as C99.

There are many implementations of the C programming language that are compilers (Clang, GCC, MSVC). I'm looking for an open source implementation of a C interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CINT - http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint
But it is not C99 AFAIK.

Comment: Open-source, though (compare to Ch).

Answer (score 2):

google "cint", "ch".

I like [tcc](http://tinycc.org/) (also there are some links that my prove fruitful in there). tcc is basically a compiler, but you call it with a shebang line

```
#!/usr/local/bin/tcc -run
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { puts("Hello, World!"); return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Ch](http://www.softintegration.com/) is "an embeddable C/C++ interpreter and scripting
language for cross-platform scripting, numerical computing,
shell programming, 2D/3D plotting, 
quick animation, and embedded scripting."