# How to port a C game to the browser

Tags: c, browser, porting

Here's my aim - to take the ASCII roguelike Angband and create an online console where users can play the game server-side. From my superficial viewpoint this seems like it *should* be doable - as there are REPL consoles that can be displayed online for a multitude of languages, so interpreting the language shouldn't be a problem, right?

Ideally, it would be as simple as running the game on the server and displaying the output to the client-side browser. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Start writing code. And yes, it's entirely doable. I recommend just using this: http://bellard.org/jslinux/ (it saves all that silly "rewriting" stuff, although I'm not entirely sure on the practicallity ;-)

Comment: [Is there an interpreter for C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c)

Comment: It might be worth it to look into Google Native Client

Comment: @MikeKwan Link please! (Let's keep up these obscure yet nifty approaches :-)

Comment: Oh right. http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the simplest -- and coolest -- solution to this sort of thing is [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten). It's literally a LLVM -> JavaScript translator. You can generate LLVM bytecode using a C compiler (using llvm-gcc or Clang), so this is a reasonably short path from C to JavaScript.

You will, of course, still need some JavaScript "glue" to create the HTML UI. Emscripten isn't *quite* that magical. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a member of the Angband devteam, I would certainly be interested in following your progress. A couple different approaches you may want to investigate include

- If you want to invest less work and are willing to put up with some security issues (or do the work to lock it down properly), [Shell in a Box](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) is an AJAX terminal emulator you could easily use to connect a browser to a shell. There are others.
- konijn started work on a [Javascript interface](http://code.google.com/p/hellband/source/browse/trunk/js/?r=946) for his Angband variant Hellband. I don't believe it's complete or stable, but it could be useful as a model.