# Writing a C-Interpreter for interactive C code

Tags: c, interpreter

I wanted to practice C, so I decided to write a C-interpreter in the spirit of the python interpreter.  I have some C knowledge, but I've always been a learn by doing type of programmer.

What I have so far, is very simple.  Just parsing the user's input, one line at a time, and distinguishing between declarations such as:

```
int x = 10;
char c = 'a';
```

where I create a struct representing the variable's type, name, and ivalue for int value and cvalue for char value.  There's a lot more to go there but one step at a time.

I can also parse function calls, as such:

```
printf("value of x = %d\n, x);
```

where I extract the name of the function, and store the args in a char** args.

It sounds silly, but I would like to avoid writing a mapper for each standard c library function, in order to execute a call to something like printf or strstr or strcpy.  Is there anyway to dynamically call a standard c function without this approach?

Also, suggestions on the design of this thing are very welcome.

Comment: Other than using `ctypes`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm writing the interpreter in C not python.

Comment: Quibble: `int x = 10;` and `char c = 'a';` are declarations with initializations, not assignment statements. If you want to implement C, you'll need to understand its syntax.

Comment: @KeithThompson Just an error in writing.  The function in my code is actually called parse_declaration

Comment: If this program is written in C, and interpreting C, it shouldn't be tagged with Python.

Comment: @andrewcooke Fair point.  Python tag dropped

Comment: http://dyncall.org/ ?

Comment: What are you using to parse the input? (I hope you know about things like the typedef name-identifier problem and the [lexer hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_lexer_hack). At least it's not something like C++ or Perl.)

Comment: I am using posix extended regex that I'm hoping to grow as I continue working on the program

Comment: That's not going to cut it for general C. Interpreters are big programs, and parsing is not a trivial problem. You may want to look into [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis), [parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator), and [context-free grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar), and this is all before you get to any part of the interpreter involved in actually running the program.

Comment: This is only intended as practice for learning C, and I'm hoping to grow it as times goes on.  For now, I am fine with limited features, like simple statements and function calls.

Comment: regex? For parsing?!? Do not ever do it again!!!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can't (as I figure) write a C interpreter.</strike>  
You'll have what I guess is a really hard time writing a C interpreter.
You'll probably have to write a compiler.
Of-course you can "dissect" the language on-the-fly, parsing the code as you progress.
The real issue (as I see it), would be with handling external references.

In Python you handle external references using the `import` keyword.
As you know, some libs may have conflicting methods (e.g. `lxml` and `libxml2`).
This conflict is resolved by `import`ing the correct library.
You can of-course think of some mechanism the effectively "links" or imports all the needed external references.
This will probably have certain very-specific assumptions.
In this way, when you encounter `#include <stdlib.h>` you actually `import` it.
For that matter, importing it would probably mean loading a dll of the `stdlib` using something like `LoadLibrary()` or `LoadLibraryEx` under windows.
After loading all the `#include's` you encounter, if you don't find a definition for a reference, then you'll probably traverse the local dir' for additional C files, until you encounter the sought reference, at which point I'm not sure what should be done.
That's regarding the linkage problem (which I honestly don't see how you'll overcome without proper compilation).

The other part is actually very-hard as well. You need to write a Lexer.
That's that little devil that parses-up all those lines of C code.
I assume you've fiddled with a Scheme/List interpreter writing, or perhaps even some more complex parser.
BE WARE!  C is not Scheme!
It is a highly complex language to parse. It's description documents span hundreds of pages.
Writing a C lexer is not an exercise in writing interpreters.
C has some nasty context-related parsing - which basically means it's not a CFL (Context Free Language) - meaning you can't write a nice finite automata to parse it.

I'll end with [an example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/02/the-context-sensitivity-of-c%E2%80%99s-grammar-revisited/) taken from the wonderful blog of [Eli Bendersky](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/).

```
typedef int AA;
void foo()
{
    AA aa;       /* OK - define variable aa of type AA */
    float AA;    /* OK - define variable AA of type float */
}
```

This just goes to show how tricky can context-related grammar be.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I started out by using [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/) and reading some lines of input, then compiling them, inside a main function, and calling that.  However, I thought there would be a better approach.  Is there a way I can compile one line a time, such that it's execution would succeed, while being able to resolve dependencies, i.e. if int x was defined three or four line prior, then the next line is int z = x + 10.

Comment: What you're talking about, would usually mean interpreting rather than compilation (I think). It seems like going via an intermediate byte-code and trying to interpret that, is the logical thing to do.

Comment: Wrong. It's perfectly possible to write an interpreter (although the difference between compiler and interpreter is pretty vague). Take a look at this, for example: https://code.google.com/p/c-semantics/

Comment: I didn't say you _can't_ write an interpreter, all I said this is a most formidable task - while pointing a couple of the obvious difficulties.

Comment: @Trevor, there is only one way your sentence "You can't write interpreter ... You must write a compiler" can be parsed. Please correct it.

Comment: True. I honestly know that every professional "decoder" for C, is a compiler - and a hand written one at that. Not even a YACC generated one. C grammer is hard! It's miles-and-miles away from a tiny "boot-leg" home-project for some wishing to experiment with interpreters or even compilers, which I assumed is the setting presumed. Sorry for not being clear enough. I still, by-the-way, think this is what the original author meant. Maybe LLVM can be considered an interpreter - I don't think that's the context of the Q.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the hassle of parsing C's grammar, it's actually pretty well-suited to interpretation because it was designed to be processed in a single pass to account for the memory constraints of 1970s equipment.

In fact, part 6 (p. 713-787) of [C: The Complete Reference, Fourth Edition](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/452670.C) by Herbert Schildt is dedicated to tying together everything the rest of the book taught by walking you through writing such an interpreter. (It's also in the third edition, which is [available](https://archive.org/details/ccompletereferen0000schi_i3l3/page/749/mode/2up) in The Internet Archive's lending library.)

I haven't checked whether the version in the book has any revisions to it, but his "Little C" was first presented to the world in [Dr. Dobb's Journal, August, 1989](https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/building-your-own-c-interpreter/184408184).

Schildt also guides readers through writing a simple C interpreter in chapter 1 of "The Craft of C: Take-Charge Programming", which is also [available](https://archive.org/details/craftofc00herb/page/1/mode/2up) via The Internet Archive's lending library.

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/584714/435253) has a bunch of answers listing existing C intepreters.

As for dynamically calling C functions, it's easier on POSIX platforms than Windows because you may need `.lib` files to resolve the symbols in your `.dll`s, while `.so` files have no equivalent.

With `.so` files, you just `dlopen` the path to the library and use `dlsym` to retrieve a function pointer by name.

An example of doing so can be found in the Linux manpage for dlopen by running `man dlopen`.