# "no main" function for linking or execution in C++

Tags: c++, linux, macos, compilation

I am trying to compile a function (not called main) that can be integrated in another code or directly executed (after linking).

I try it one my mac, and work well.
I finally test it on Linux (CentOS and ubuntu). However, the task looks harder as expected on Linux.

The source code is the following one (just to explain the problem)

test.cpp:

```
#include <cstdio>

#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif
    int test(int argc, char const *argv[]);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

int test(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "test");
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation line on MacOS

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o && g++ test.o -o test -e _test
```

and on Linux

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o && g++ test.o -o test -e test
```

I try on my MacOS with clang, g++ and Intel compiler, all 3 works fine.

And I try with g++ and the Intel compiler on Linux, always, the same error.

```
usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any advice, explanation or solution, on what I am doing wrong or missing would be very helpful.
Thanks

Edit:

Currently, I have a "define" to create a main, but if we have lots of function we are obligated to do two compilations each time (one for the function version and one for the execution) and make finally the code heavier.

Like discussed in this topic [is there a GCC compiler/linker option to change the name of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097825/is-there-a-gcc-compiler-linker-option-to-change-the-name-of-main)

To don't do a XY I inherited from a bunch of small programs that I want to put to gather, that it is easier to use (for remote execution ...). However, each one need to be able to be executed independently if needed, for debugging,... I hesitate, between using "execv" and just convert each main as a function. I probably take the bad chose.

Edit:
The final goal is to be able to have independent programs. But that we can call from an external software too.

Solution:
The solution looks to be, to a call to  the main through a dlopen

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Please edit your question to motivate it.

Comment: I don't understand your edit. Why are you required to make two compilations? Which ones? And why does that matter? Smells badly like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You can't call any C functions if you are not linking and executing the C runtime.

Comment: @MathieuGravey: Please **edit your question** don't comment it. But why can't you have libraries? Smells very badly like some XY problem. What is the original issue you want to tackle?

Comment: The latest edits make your question even more confusing. You really should explain the original issue you want to solve. We can't guess your motivations. Why plugins & shared libraries are not satisfactory ?

Comment: If I could, I would downvote that question twice. The latest edits don't give any motivation, and I explicitly asked for them.

Comment: Even the mention of "goal is to be able to have independent programs" makes no sense

Comment: @MathieuGravey: spend at least a *week* reading material before coding a single line of code. You look *very* confused and you are lacking basic knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that (and even if it appears to work on MacOSX it is implementation specific and [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Linux [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) is doing more complex stuff that what you think.

The C standard (e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for C11) requires a `main` function for hosted implementations (§5.1.2.2.1) :

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype  for  this  function.

And the C++ standard also [requires a `main`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) and strongly requires some processing (e.g. construction of static data) to be done *before* `main` is running and *after* it has returned (and various crt0 tricks are implementing that feature on Linux).

If you want to understand gory details (and they are not easy!), study the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) and the (free software) source code of the implementation of the crt0.

> I am trying to compile a function (not called main) that can be integrated in another code

BTW, to use dynamically some code (e.g. [plug-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing))) from another program, consider using the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker). I recommend using the POSIX compliant [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) on [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) shared libraries. It works on most Unix flavors (including MacOSX & Linux & Solaris & AIX). For C++ code beware of [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) so read at least the [C++ dlopen mini howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/C++-dlopen.pdf).

Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

> Problems with libraries, they cannot be executed, no ?

I don't understand what that means. You certainly can load a plugin then run code inside it from the main program `dlopen`-ing it.

<sup>(and on Linux, some libraries like `libc.so` are even specially built to also work as an executable; I don't recommend this practice for your own code)</sup>

You might take several days to read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (but it is advanced stuff).

---

If you want to add some code at runtime, read also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26697146/841108) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33809944/841108).

> The final goal is to be able to have independent program. But that we can call from an external software too

You can't do that (and it would make no sense). However, you could have conventions for communicating with other running programs (i.e. [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))), using [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) such as [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s and many others. Read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) first and before coding. Read also [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

> The solution looks to be, to a call to the main through a dlopen

Calling the `main` function via `dlopen` & `dlsym` is forbidden by the C++ standard (which disallows using a pointer to `main`). The `main`  function has a very specific status and role (and is compiled specially; the compiler knows about `main`).

<sup>(perhaps calling `main`  obtained by `dlsym`  would appear to work on some Linux systems, but it certainly is undefined behavior so you should not do that)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, a lot for all these links (you add them faster that I read).
But definitely, it's the solution to my problem. I didn't know that we can do that.

Comment: @MathieuGravey: Can't you **edit** please **your own question to add the actual motivation** (which you did not tell). Please do that