# How to check that a method always returns a value

Tags: compiler-construction, compilation

I wrote a compiler which is already working decently. It checks that all non-void methods do have at least one return statement, but it does not check whether all code paths within a non-void method return a value. So, for example, if I have the following code:

```
int function(bool a) 
{
     if(a){
         return 5;
     }
}
```

It will compile "fine" and if a is false, control will drop off the function and keep executing whatever is defined under the function.

Is there some algorithm I can use to perform this check so that I always know if a method is always returning a value? Or will I need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: For quite a few compiler tricks there are already algorithms available, including recommended internal representation etc. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis Reading commented source code of an existing compiler for the same language (looks like `C` in your case, so pick a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c) is probably the best way to [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your otherwise unclear and broad question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions cannot "fall off the end" and start executing code outside of their scope, regardless of whether they return a value or not. It's common to allow the final `return` statement to be omitted for functions which do not return a result (or in some undisciplined languages even for functions which do return a result), but the function needs to return in all cases.

Given that, the simplest way to produce error messages for non-void functions which fall of the end is:

- The parser inserts a `return` statement at the end of the function body.
- Dead code elimination is used to remove the inserted `return` statement in case it is unnecessary.
- Typechecking is used to verify that all `return` statements, included the inserted one if it hasn't been deleted, are consistent with the return type of the function. (That is, since the generated `return` statement has no value, it can only be consistent with a `void` function.)

In this scenario, you need to delete unnecessary `return` statements before typechecking, or you'll end up with a lot of incorrect error messages. That requires some control flow analysis.

If that's too much work, you can issue the error message at run-time by compiling the no-value `return` statement as an error operation in the case that the function returns a value.

Comment: While that does indeed fix the "fall off the end" issue, I don't think that was the question. The question, as I understood it, was how to produce a compile time error if not all of the paths return a value.

Comment: I do what you suggest for functions that don't return a value. But can't do the same for those that do, because I can't simply guess what the return value will be. Obviusly functions falling off the end shouldn't happen. What I was asking is how to detect this situation so that the compiler reports an error and halts compilation.

Comment: @sepp2k Exactly, that is what I meant.

Comment: The fall off the end issue is fixed the way @rici suggests.

Comment: @sepp2k: I edited the answer to make it more clear that I was trying to answer the original question. Although I don't think that it is different from the previous answer, aside from some cosmetics.

Comment: Thanks, now it makes more sense to me.