# C programming language vs scripting

Tags: c

Please tell me the difference between C programming language and C scripting language .Both are same or different?and if its different tell me good link to learn C scripting as beginer

Comment: There is no "C scripting language"

Comment: @AaronMcDaid over the years C exists many developers tried to create such language, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c

Comment: There is no distinction. My guess is that some folk refer to "quick and dirty c" as being C scripting. Or perhaps even C that's passed through an interpreter rather than compiled. If you want to learn C the best book IMO is the one by Kernighan and Ritchie, and make sure you complete all the example exercises.

Comment: Googling yields: There /is/ at least one C-scripting language even going by that name: http://csl.sourceforge.net/csl.html

Comment: is csh (c-shell) considered a c-scripting language? ;)

Comment: As a beginner, you might take interest in the question: Which "real" and which scripting languages are worth investing the time to learn them?

Comment: This is the first time that I heard about C Scripting.

Answer (score 2):

By "C scripting language", you probably mean this: http://csl.sourceforge.net/csl.html or some other project to create an interpretable version of C (see [Is there an interpreter for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c))

What's the difference? Well, "C" normally refers to a compiled version of the language, and "C scripting language" normally refers to an interpreted one. That's all there is to it. From the point of view of the language's standard, there might not be an actual difference between a compiled and an interpreted implementation if both follow the standard.

Comment: C is just a language. Needing to be compiled is not part of the language specification.

Comment: @juanchopanza: you're perfectly right, I didn't make it clear enough originally. And-wow-2 downvotes in, like, 2 seconds! =)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I removed my down-vote. It is hard to give good answers to ill-defined questions.

Comment: @Mints97 I will give you an up vote if you add to your answer, that the difference between c and c scripting languages is, that C is worth learning, while there are tons of more vital scripting languages to learn than some random c-scripting language.

Comment: Its not an ill-defined question....