# Is there a shell for quickly experimenting in C?

Tags: c, linux

I'm not looking for csh, I'm looking for a shell for C similar to the Python or the Scala shells.

I understand that C is a compiled language, but is there anything out there that would let me quickly play around with things so I can e.g. better learn how pointers work? It should at least be theoretically possible to do this, wondering if anyone has taken the time to implement it.

Comment: You can evaluate C-expressions interactively in gdb.

Comment: try this https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: @EOF how do I setup a GDB session to just interactively run C code?

Answer (score 1):

As you well know that C is a compiled language. It is better to write C code than compile it, do some breakpoints, learn what value is in memory, where the pointer points etc.

But I think you mean this. [Is there an interpreter for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c)