# Dynamically change the running code by writing into the __FILE__?

Tags: c

I got to know of a way to print the source code of a running code in C using the `__FILE__` macro. As such I can seek the location and use `putchar()` to alter the contents of the file.

Is it possible to dynamically change the running code using this method?

Comment: Even if you modified the original source code, you would need to recompile the new code after for it to do anything, then relaunch it.

Comment: Remember that C is generally a compiled language.  You can change the source code all you want, but it's not going to make any difference until you recompile it.  And then even if you recompile it, it's not going to make any difference until you kill the old, running copy, and run the recompiled version.

Comment: With a compiled executable, you would need to write new assembly directly over the old program running in RAM in order to alter the running copy of the program.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to dynamically change the running code using this method ?

*No*, because once a program is compiled it no longer depends on the source file.

If you want learn how to alter the behavior of an process that is already running from within the process itself, you need to learn about assembly for the architecture you're using, the executable file format on your system, and the process API on your system, at the very least.

Comment: Or less of that and simply use an embeddable compiler such as [gcc jit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/jit/).

Answer (score 5):

As most other answers are explaining, in practical terms, most C implementations are [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler)s. So the [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) that is running has only an indirect (and delayed) relation with the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code), because the source code had to be processed by the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) to produce that executable.

<sup>Remember that a programming language is (not a software but...) a *specification*, written in some report. Read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), draft specification of [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)). Most implementations of C are command-line compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) & [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) in the [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) realm), even if you [might](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584720/841108) find [interpreters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_%28computing%29).</sup>

However, with some [*operating systems*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (notably POSIX ones, such as MacOSX and Linux), you could [dynamically load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) some [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29). Or you could create, in some other way (such as [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries like [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) or [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) or [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)), a *fresh* function and *dynamically* get a pointer to it (and that is not stricto sensu conforming to the C standard, where a function pointer should point to some *existing* function of your program).

On Linux, you might generate (at runtime of your own program, linked with `-rdynamic` to have its names usable from plugins, and with `-ldl` library to get the dynamic loader) some C code in some temporary source file e.g. `/tmp/gencode.c`, run a compilation (using e.g. [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) or [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)) of that emitted code as a `/tmp/gencode.so` plugin thru a command like e.g. 
 `gcc -O1 -g -Wall -fPIC -shared /tmp/gencode.c -o /tmp/gencode.so`, then dynamically load that plugin using [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), find function pointers (from some conventional name) in that loaded plugin with [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html), and call indirectly that function pointer. My [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program shows that is possible for many hundred thousands of generated C files and loaded plugins. I'm using similar tricks in my [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/289379/40065) and [that](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/323824/40065). Notice that you don't really "[self-modify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code)" C code, you more broadly generate *additional* C code, compile it (as some plugin, etc...), and then load it -as an extension or plugin- then use it.

<sup>(for pragmatical reasons including ease of debugging, I don't recommend *overwriting* some existing C file, but just emitting new C code in some fresh temporary `.c` file -from some internal [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)-like representation- that you would later feed to the compiler)</sup>

> Is it possible to dynamically change the running code?

In general (at least on Linux and most POSIX systems), the machine code sits in a read-only [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment) of the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) so you cannot change or overwrite it; but you can use indirection thru function pointers (in your C code) to call newly loaded code (e.g. from `dlopen`-ed plugins).

However, you might also read about [homoiconic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) languages, [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming), [multi-staged programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-stage_programming), and try to use Common Lisp (e.g. using its [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) implementation, which compile to machine code at every [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) interaction and at every [eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval)). I also recommend reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) (an excellent and freely available introduction to programming, with some chapters related to metaprogramming approaches)

<sup>PS. Dynamic loading of plugins is also possible in Windows -which I don't know- with [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but with a very different (and incompatible) model. Read Levine's [*linkers and loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/).</sup>

Answer (score 4):

A computer doesn't understand the code as we do. It compiles or interprets it and loads into memory. Our modification of code is just changing the file. One needs to compile it and link it with other libraries and load it into memory.

`ptrace()` is a syscall used to inject code into a running program. You can probably look into that and achieve whatever you are trying to do.

[Inject hello world](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6210) in a running program. I have tried and tested this sometime before.

Comment: Awesome thing to know about ..can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: I can provide with links to help you. I myself have had a mild encounter with this problem and even little success. but that was more of laze and lack of motivation.

Comment: You don't need `ptrace`  to add code into a running process. It is much easier to use `dlopen`. See my answer.