# Trying to "pip install reportlab==3.0" and I get a crazy long error with include header <string.h>

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pip, reportlab

I am trying to `pip install reportlab==3.0` and I am not having any luck getting past this error. Can someone tell me what I am missing? The latest version of reportlab installs okay but I can't use that.

I have tried easy_install and all versions. It seems that < 3.0 I will get the same error but with > 3.0 I am okay.

I have also made sure my headers are linked. It looks like towards the end there is even some javascript errors? This has had me stumped

```
#Attempting install of _rl_accel & pyHnj
#extensions from '/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
################################################
################################################
#Attempting install of _renderPM
#extensions from '/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM'
will use package libart 2.3.12
# installing without freetype no ttf, sorry!
# You need to install a static library version of the freetype2 software
# If you need truetype support in renderPM
# You may need to edit setup.cfg (win32)
# or edit this file to access the library if it is installed
################################################
Standard T1 font curves already downloaded
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab
copying src/reportlab/rl_config.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab
copying src/reportlab/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab
copying src/reportlab/rl_settings.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics
creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts
copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/slidebox.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts
copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/doughnut.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts
copying src/reportlab/graphics/charts/piecharts.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/graphics/charts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ab_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ai_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_a______.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/cobo____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/cob_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/com_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/coo_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ebi____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_eb_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_ei_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/_er_____.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/sy______.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/zd______.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/zx______.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/fonts/zy______.pfb -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/fonts
copying src/reportlab/lib/hyphen.mashed -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib
running build_ext
building 'reportlab.lib._rl_accel' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.o
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:122:10: warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
                inData = PyBytes_AsString(_o1);
                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:133:9: warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        inData = PyBytes_AsString(inObj);
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:222:10: warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
                inData = PyBytes_AsString(_o1);
                       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:233:9: warning: assigning to 'unsigned char *' from 'char *' converts between pointers to integer types with different sign [-Wpointer-sign]
        inData = PyBytes_AsString(inObj);
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:956:82: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') [-Wformat]
                        PyErr_Format(PyExc_AttributeError,"Bad size %d('%s') for attribute character",PyBytes_GET_SIZE(value),v);
                                                                    ~~                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                                    %zd
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:58:28: note: expanded from macro 'PyBytes_GET_SIZE'
#       define PyBytes_GET_SIZE         PyString_GET_SIZE
                                        ^
/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7/stringobject.h:92:32: note: expanded from macro 'PyString_GET_SIZE'
#define PyString_GET_SIZE(op)  Py_SIZE(op)
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7/object.h:116:33: note: expanded from macro 'Py_SIZE'
#define Py_SIZE(ob)             (((PyVarObject*)(ob))->ob_size)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
5 warnings generated.
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib/_rl_accel.so
building 'reportlab.lib.pyHnj' extension
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/pyHnjmodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/pyHnjmodule.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/hyphen.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/hyphen.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/hnjalloc.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/hnjalloc.o
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -L/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/lib build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/pyHnjmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/hyphen.o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/hnjalloc.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/reportlab/lib/pyHnj.so
building 'reportlab.graphics._renderPM' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/_renderPM.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.o
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.c:604:28: warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++);
                                  ^
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.c:604:28: note: put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-parset1.c:710:1: warning: function 'print_value_deep' is not needed and will not be emitted [-Wunneeded-internal-declaration]
print_value_deep (Gt1PSContext *psc, Gt1Value *val, int nest)
^
2 warnings generated.
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-dict.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-dict.o
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DLIBART_COMPILATION -DLIBART_VERSION="2.3.12" -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/libart_lgpl -I/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1 -I/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/include/python2.7 -c /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.o
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:100:9: error: implicitly declaring library function 'strlen' with type 'unsigned long (const char *)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  len = strlen (s);
        ^
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:100:9: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strlen'
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:102:3: error: implicitly declaring library function 'memcpy' with type 'void *(void *, const void *, unsigned long)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  memcpy (new, s, len);
  ^
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:102:3: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'memcpy'
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:172:10: error: implicitly declaring library function 'strcmp' with type 'int (const char *, const char *)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    if (!strcmp (nc->table[i & mask].name, name))
         ^
/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/src/rl_addons/renderPM/gt1/gt1-namecontext.c:172:10: note: include the header <string.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'strcmp'
3 errors generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of reportlab
Command "/Users/andynguyen/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-f2sZ79-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-build-L1Xdbd/reportlab/
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

UPDATE:
Error looks similar except that bottom portion now looks like

```
In file included from /private/var/folders/x6/wyq9wg250c7d7s933sp1fgtw0000gn/T/pip-install-cmDQfb/reportlab/src/rl_addons/rl_accel/_rl_accel.c:8:
/opt/anaconda3/envs/aggvenv/include/python2.7/Python.h:33:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you try upgrading pip?

Comment: @CForce99 I did. Been going at this for hours lol

Comment: and you still get the same error?

Comment: Similar @CForce99 I added an update

Comment: Did you try downloading it via Anaconda ?

Comment: Yeah it actually got me this far @TungNg

Answer (score 1):

Install xcode.

```
xcode-select --install
```

if you still have issues look in to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761599) for all the follow up instructions.

Comment: It didn't. I have this installed I even tried uninstalling and installing. It looks like I am getting this when I am in my virtualenv. I can installed reportlab==3.0 fine when not in venv

Comment: I am trying to follow up, are you still having this issue?

Comment: Hello I was able to solve it by uninstalling my CommandLineTools and reinstalling and then creating a symbolic link to the MacOSX sdk file.

Comment: @AndyNguyen: Can you please provide a detailed procedure on how you did it?

Comment: @RabihKodeih Man it was a trip. Are you getting the exact same error? I deleted and uninstalled xcode command line tools, ran brew install gcc and libtool. From there I received a few new errors which I followed. It was along the lines of pointing clang to where my command line tools were since I uninstalled them. Try reinstalling the command line tool and then installing gcc and see what you get.

Comment: @AndyNguyen. Thanks for the update. What I actually did was downloading the source and adding the missing "#include <strings.h>" in the related C file then building via "python setup.py --build" or "python setup.py --install". Of course I did this in a special venv'ed folder then copied the resulting reportlab folder and wheel from site-packages to the real desired destination. The problem in my case wasn't that the standard C headers include dir wasn't visible it was rather a problematic use of a C-compiler directive in the source code.