MacOS Cannot Install Jekyll
I can't install jekyll. I'm on MacOS 13.6.6. I've tried xcode-select --install and xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools as well as gem update --system. Nothing has worked and I keep getting the same message:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.8.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.8.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20241203-56969-vts81m sitelibdir\=./.gem.20241203-56969-vts81m clean

current directory: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.8.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20241203-56969-vts81m sitelibdir\=./.gem.20241203-56969-vts81m
compiling ruby_http_parser.c
warning: unknown warning option '-Wno-cast-function-type'; did you mean '-Wno-bad-function-cast'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
warning: unknown warning option '-Wmisleading-indentation'; did you mean '-Wbinding-in-condition'? [-Wunknown-warning-option]
In file included from ruby_http_parser.c:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby.h:38:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:25:
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/include/ruby-3.3.0/ruby/defines.h:16:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
2 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: *** [ruby_http_parser.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-22/3.3.0/http_parser.rb-0.8.0/gem_make.out
Successfully installed bundler-2.5.23
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.5.23
Done installing documentation for bundler after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

This is what my gem environment looks like:
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.5.23
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.3.6 (2024-11-05 patchlevel 108) [x86_64-darwin22]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/engrpckg/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/engrpckg/.cache/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-darwin-22
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
     - /Users/engrpckg/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.3.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.3.6/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/TeX/texbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin
     - /var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin
     - /Users/engrpckg/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I've tried xcode-select --install as well as xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools, as I believed it may be an xcode issue. But this doesn't seem to help, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Are you sure macOS 13 is still supported by the whole toolchain? You might have better luck using something like rbenv, but that's just a guess.

The compiler is not finding stdio.h. I think you will find the solution among the answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511046/823617
