# Ch and CInt C interpreters

Tags: c, interpreter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Have you used any of the C++ interpreters (not compilers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers)

#### probable duplicate: [Have you used any of the C++ interpreters (not compilers)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers)

---

Who has used Ch and CInt? Does anyone have a preference for either? Differences/Disadvantages/ advantages of each?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers is the earliest of the several duplicates (and being a particle physicist I use ROOT and thus cint. It works fine. Doesn't like nested templates, however.)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find that when I first searched for it.

Comment: It's on the second page in the obvious search (`[c++] interpreters`), so it is easy to miss. Probably why there are N versions of it.

Comment: @dmckee : Put your comment in an answer and ask archgoon to accept the answer...