# read-eval-print loop (REPL) for several languages

Tags: java, c++, c, read-eval-print-loop

I was wondering if there are some recommended [read-eval-print loop (REPL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) respectively for

(1) C++

(2) C

(3) Java

Thanks!

Comment: The c and c++ parts of this question have been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c) [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383348/ch-and-cint-c-interpreters-closed) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775674/is-it-possible-to-build-a-interactive-c-shell) and [over](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189097/c-interpreter-console-snippet-compiler) [again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers). Search. It's your friend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## C and C++

You can use CERN's [cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint).

## Java

You can use [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), or if you don't care so much about having Java syntax (e.g. your goal is just to make sure the *classes* do what you want), you can use Groovy, Scala, JRuby, or Jython.

Comment: it seems cint has been discontinued.http://old.nabble.com/Cint7-Status-tt26503422.html#a26503422

Comment: Apparently (from that email), plans are in the works to create an LLVM-based C and C++ interpreter. In the mean time, you can still get and install cint 5.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren’t languages that support a [dynamic `eval` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

Comment: Thanks but do you mean the same thing as REPL?

Comment: Eval is the second of three steps in the Read-Eval-Print-Loop. It is very much a prerequisite. An interpreter can be created that has an `eval`-like function for these languages, but it is not part of the language specification, and most such interpreters have limitations.

Comment: This answer is manifestly wrong. It isn't necessary that the language support `eval`, it is necessary that you have an *environment* that can evaluate statements in the language. Note, also that Ken has provided answer for two for the three questions.

Comment: @dmckee: Strong disagree.  If you expect to type arbitrary expressions to be evaluated according to C, C++, or Java, then you **are** asking to implement an expression parser that is equivalent to what the compiler does.  That is what is normally meant by read-eval-print loop. This is trivial in an interpreted language and a royal PITA in a compiled one.

Comment: The answer does not have to do anything with the question. Op wants A, answer states fact B.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Java REPL using the javax.tools.JavaCompiler interface here: http://www.scravy.de/blog/2012-02-27/a-read-eval-print-loop-for-java.htm (runs on the command line).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be avalaible in Java 9 coming september 22 of 2016.

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222