# Is it possible to build a interactive C shell?

Tags: c, shell, interactive, read-eval-print-loop

I'm just wondering if this is possible using either (Python, Java or C)? I'm looking for something like IPython for Python.

Comment: See [
Have you used any of the C++ interpreters (not compilers)?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers/) and [
Is there an interpreter for C?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c).

Comment: There is a very neat C++ interpreter in IRC (##c++) called Geordi: http://www.eelis.net/geordi/ So you can test it without installing.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, and such things already exist, you just have to google for them :-)

- [Ch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter) is one popular example
- [CINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CINT) is another

That said, actually *developing* a functional interpreter like this from scratch is much more difficult than finding one online. So now it depends on what's behind your question - do you want just an interpreter to use? Then pick one of the linked above. Do you want to develop such an interpreter? Well, then start [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compilation).

Answer (score 4):

[GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), or any other debugger such as the [ups debugger](http://ups.sourceforge.net/), will generally implement a subset of C that can be used interactively.

There is also the [Ch C interpreter](http://www.softintegration.com/), a commercial C interpreter, and the open source [ccons C interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/ccons/), which is based on [clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[c-repl](http://neugierig.org/software/c-repl/) should fit the bill.