# command line interactive shell for C

Tags: c, command-line

Is there any command line interactive shell for C just like in Python ?
Actually, I'd like to make one if its not done, at least if a stable one is still not present.

I'm good at C and basics of python.. 
What all things I should be knowing to really do this kind of project ?

Comment: See the many results of [searching for "c interpreter"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interpreter+%5Bc%5D&submit=search) and also for ["c++ interpreter"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=interpreter+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D&submit=search).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an interpreter for C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [c-repl](http://neugierig.org/software/c-repl/).

There is some SO discussion on the package in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459678/where-can-i-find-c-repl-documentation).

The project might be old; there have been no checkins to its [github master branch](https://github.com/martine/c-repl) since October, 2009.

UPDATE - I found this SO question which has better answers: [Is it possible to build a interactive C shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775674/is-it-possible-to-build-a-interactive-c-shell)

Answer (score 0):

> Cling is an interactive C++ interpreter… [that] realizes the read-eval-print loop (REPL) concept, in order to leverage rapid application development

[See project page on Github](https://github.com/vgvassilev/cling)