# Turning strings into code?

Tags: c, string, io, interpreter

So let's say I have a string containing some code in C, predictably read from a file that has other things in it besides normal C code. How would I turn this string into code usable by the program? Do I have to write an entire interpreter, or is there a library that already does this for me? The code in question may call subroutines that I declared in my actual C file, so one that only accounts for stock C commands may not work.

Comment: This is an extremely non-trivial exercise, and raises the obvious question: what is the overall goal here?  There is probably a better overall solution.

Comment: Did you try C interpreters ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539/have-you-used-any-of-the-c-interpreters-not-compilers/72792#72792 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoo.  With C this is actually pretty hard.

You've basically got a couple of options:

#### interpret the code

To do this, you'll hae to write an interpreter, and interpreting C is a fairly hard problem.  There have been C interpreters available in the past, but I haven't read about one recently.  In any case, unless you *reallY really* need this, writing your own interpreter is a *big* project.

[Googling](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=h9&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=open%20source%20C%20interpreter&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=4892cb34971d8ce7&ix=h9&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1576&bih=994) does show a couple of open-source (partial) C interpreters, like [picoc](http://code.google.com/p/picoc/)

#### compile and dynamically load

If you can capture the code and wrap it so it makes a syntactically complete C source file, then you can compile it into a C dynamically loadable library: a DLL in Windows, or a .so in more variants of UNIX.  Then you could load the result at runtime.

Now, what normally would lead someone to do this is a need to be able to express some complicated scripting functions.  Have you considered the possibility of using a *different* language?  Python, Scheme (guile) and Lua are easily available to add as a scripting language to a C application.

Comment: K, never mind then! I could certainly reduce the input to a bunch of string keywords, but the ensuing code is going to be so much uglier than what it could have been, but I see why this is so hard. I guess the difficulty of doing this to a language is inversely proportional to how high-level it is! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

C has nothing of this nature.  That's because C is compiled, and the compiler needs to do a lot of building of the code before the code starts running (hence receives a string as input) that it can't really change on the fly that easily.  Compiled languages have a rigidity to them while interpreted languages have a flexibility.

You're thinking of Perl, Python PHP etc. and so called "fourth generation languages."  I'm sure there's a technical term in c.s. for this flexibility, but C doesn't have it.  You'll need to switch to one of these languages (and give up performance) if you have a task that requires this sort of string use much.  Check out Perl's `/e` flag with regexes, for instance.

In C, you'll need to design your application so you don't need to do this.  This is generally quite doable, as for its non-OO-ness and other deficiencies many huge, complex applications run on well-written C just fine.